# How to run multiple functions at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I'm trying to run 2 functions at the same time.

```
def func1():
    print('Working')

def func2():
    print('Working')

func1()
func2()
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How can I run python functions in parallel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207309/python-how-can-i-run-python-functions-in-parallel)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Do this:

```
from threading import Thread

def func1():
    print('Working')

def func2():
    print("Working")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = func1).start()
    Thread(target = func2).start()
```

Comment: He might want to know that because of the Global Interpreter Lock they will not execute at the exact same time even if the machine in question has multiple CPUs. http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: @joaquin -- Your right, sorry forgot to take the function exectutions out after copy and paste.

Comment: How do get results when the functions return something?

Comment: There's no reason to use two import statements. Just use the second.

Comment: How do you supply arguments to the function?

Comment: I have tried this, but it does not work if i have `return` instead of `print`.
How can I run this with `return` statement?

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work if each thread eventually goes running another process. In this case only one process executes at the same time.

Comment: @stallingOne
Please look into concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: @HKay Since 5 years I have been using a global variable and it works fine.

Comment: This is NOT an answer to the question as it clearly states "at the same time".

Answer (score 16):

[The answer about threading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2957131) is good, but you need to be a bit more specific about what you want to do.

If you have two functions that both use a lot of CPU, threading (in CPython) will probably get you nowhere. Then you might want to have a look at the [multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) or possibly you might want to use jython/IronPython.

If CPU-bound performance is the reason, you could even implement things in (non-threaded) C and get a much bigger speedup than doing two parallel things in python.

Without more information, it isn't easy to come up with a good answer.

Answer (score 12):

This can be done elegantly with [Ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray), a system that allows you to easily parallelize and distribute your Python code.

To parallelize your example, you'd need to define your functions with the `@ray.remote decorator`, and then invoke them with `.remote`.

```
import ray

ray.init()

# Define functions you want to execute in parallel using 
# the ray.remote decorator.
@ray.remote
def func1():
    print("Working")

@ray.remote
def func2():
    print("Working")

# Execute func1 and func2 in parallel.
ray.get([func1.remote(), func2.remote()])
```

If `func1()` and `func2()` return results, you need to rewrite the above code a bit, by replacing `ray.get([func1.remote(), func2.remote()])` with:

```
ret_id1 = func1.remote()
ret_id2 = func1.remote()
ret1, ret2 = ray.get([ret_id1, ret_id2])
```

There are a number of advantages of using Ray over the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module or using multithreading. In particular, the **same code** will run on a single machine as well as on a cluster of machines.

For more advantages of Ray see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548628/how-to-do-parallel-programming-in-python/48177988#48177988).

Answer (score 4):

One option, that looks like it makes two functions run *at the same

time*, is using the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/threading.html) module (example in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2957131/3787376) answer).

However, it has a small delay, as an Official Python Documentation
[page](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#threading.Thread) describes. A better module to try using is [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Also, there's other Python modules that can be used for *asynchronous execution* (two pieces of code working at the same time). For some information about them and help to choose one, you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629680/deciding-between-subprocess-multiprocessing-and-thread-in-python) Stack Overflow question.

#### Comment from another user about the `threading` module

> He might want to know that because of the Global Interpreter Lock
>   they will not execute at the exact same time even if the machine in
>   question has multiple CPUs. [wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)

– Jonas Elfström [Jun 2 '10 at 11:39](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957116/make-2-functions-run-at-the-same-time#comment3014927_2957131)

#### Quote from the Documentation about `threading` module not working

> CPython implementation detail: In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter
>   Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though
>   certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation).
>
> If you want your application to make better use of the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to use multiprocessing or concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.
>   However, threading is still an appropriate model if you
>   want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.

Comment: I append time.time() at the end of each print() function and limit the loop to9 times on the code of the other answer. Here is what I see in my terminal: ('a', 1509314761.857559) ('a', 1509314761.857664) ('a', 1509314761.85767) ('a', 1509314761.857675) ('a', 1509314761.85768) ('a', 1509314761.857685) ('a', 1509314761.85769) ('a', 1509314761.857695) ('a', 1509314761.857699) ('b', 1509314761.858138) ('b', 1509314761.858224) ('b', 1509314761.858229) ('b', 1509314761.858234) ('b', 1509314761.858239) ('b', 1509314761.858244) ('b', 1509314761.858249) ('b', 1509314761.858253) ('b', 1509314761.858258)

Comment: Even with multiprocessing, it's not really concurrent rite? one runs after the other.

Comment: @weefwefwqg3 Check the links in my answer to details about the modules. You can also check yourself but the official documentation should explain.

Comment: Idk if it's a bug, but for me multiprocessing does not work. The line `thr1 = Process(target=run_foo(), args=())` which weren't supposed to create a thread yet *(because I didn't run `thr1.start()`)* actually creates it, and so the process that should in turn be launched by `run_foo()` steals execution, so no multithreading.

Answer (score 3):

The thread module does work simultaneously unlike multiprocess, but the timing is a bit off. The code below prints a "1" and a "2". These are called by different functions respectively. I did notice that when printed to the console, they would have slightly different timings.

```
from threading import Thread

def one():
    while(1 == num):
        print("1")
        time.sleep(2)
    
def two():
    while(1 == num):
        print("2")
        time.sleep(2)


p1 = Thread(target = one)
p2 = Thread(target = two)

p1.start()
p2.start()
```

Output: (Note the space is for the wait in between printing)

```
1
2

2
1

12
   
21

12
   
1
2
```

Not sure if there is a way to correct this, or if it matters at all. Just something I noticed.

Answer (score 2):

In case you also want to **wait** until both functions have been completed:

```
from threading import Thread

def func1():
    print 'Working'

def func2():
    print 'Working'

# Define the threads and put them in an array
threads = [
    Thread(target = self.func1),
    Thread(target = self.func2)
]

# Func1 and Func2 run in separate threads
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

# Wait until both Func1 and Func2 have finished
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
from threading import Thread

def fun1():
    print("Working1")
def fun2():
    print("Working2")

t1 = Thread(target=fun1)
t2 = Thread(target=fun2)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Comment: Add an insight to how this solves the OP's requirement

Comment: how can i do this with return statement, it only works if function has print

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to run multiple functions concurrently in python is using `asyncio` that I couldn't see within the answers.

```py
import asyncio

async def func1():
    for _ in range(5):
        print(func1.__name__)
        await asyncio.sleep(0)  # switches tasks every iteration.

async def func2():
    for _ in range(5):
        print(func2.__name__)
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

tasks = [func1(), func2()]
await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Out:

```
func1
func2
func1
func2
func1
func2
func1
func2
func1
func2
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- The above `asyncio` syntax is valid on python 3.7 and later
- [multiprocessing vs multithreading vs asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27435284/3702377)

Answer (score 1):

This code below can run 2 functions parallelly:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

def test1():
    print("Test1")

def test2():
    print("Test2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process1 = Process(target=test1)
    process2 = Process(target=test2)
    process1.start()
    process2.start()
    process1.join()
    process2.join()
```

Result:

```
Test1
Test2
```

And, these 2 sets of code below can run 2 functions concurrently:

```py
from threading import Thread

def test1():
    print("Test1")

def test2():
    print("Test2")

thread1 = Thread(target=test1)
thread2 = Thread(target=test2)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

```py
from operator import methodcaller
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def test1():
    print("Test1")

def test2():
    print("Test2")

caller = methodcaller("__call__")
ThreadPool().map(caller, [test1, test2])
```

Result:

```
Test1
Test2
```

And, this code below can run 2 `async` functions concurrently and asynchronously:

```py
import asyncio

async def test1():
    print("Test1")
        
async def test2():
    print("Test2")
        
async def call_tests():
    await asyncio.gather(test1(), test2())

asyncio.run(call_tests())
```

Result:

```
Test1
Test2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to convey can be achieved through multiprocessing. However if you want to do it through threads you can do this.
This might help

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def func1():
    print 'Working'
    time.sleep(2)

def func2():
    print 'Working'
    time.sleep(2)

th = Thread(target=func1)
th.start()
th1=Thread(target=func2)
th1.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

**test using APscheduler:**

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime
Future = dt.now() + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=2550)  # 2.55 seconds from now testing start accuracy

def myjob1():
    print('started job 1: ' + str(dt.now())[:-3])  # timed to millisecond because thats where it varies
    time.sleep(5)
    print('job 1 half at: ' + str(dt.now())[:-3])
    time.sleep(5)
    print('job 1 done at: ' + str(dt.now())[:-3])
def myjob2():
    print('started job 2: ' + str(dt.now())[:-3])
    time.sleep(5)
    print('job 2 half at: ' + str(dt.now())[:-3])
    time.sleep(5)
    print('job 2 done at: ' + str(dt.now())[:-3])

print(' current time: ' + str(dt.now())[:-3])
print('  do job 1 at: ' + str(Future)[:-3] + ''' 
  do job 2 at: ''' + str(Future)[:-3])
sched.add_job(myjob1, 'date', run_date=Future)
sched.add_job(myjob2, 'date', run_date=Future)
```

**i got these results. which proves they are running at the same time.**

```
 current time: 2020-12-15 01:54:26.526
  do job 1 at: 2020-12-15 01:54:29.072  # i figure these both say .072 because its 1 line of print code
  do job 2 at: 2020-12-15 01:54:29.072
started job 2: 2020-12-15 01:54:29.075  # notice job 2 started before job 1, but code calls job 1 first.
started job 1: 2020-12-15 01:54:29.076  
job 2 half at: 2020-12-15 01:54:34.077  # halfway point on each job completed same time accurate to the millisecond
job 1 half at: 2020-12-15 01:54:34.077
job 1 done at: 2020-12-15 01:54:39.078  # job 1 finished first. making it .004 seconds faster.
job 2 done at: 2020-12-15 01:54:39.091  # job 2 was .002 seconds faster the second test
```

Answer (score 0):

**we can do this by using multiple processing(use multiple CPU) or multiple threading(use multi thread of a single CPU):**

**Example of multiple threading:**

```
from threading import Thread

def fun_square(x):
    x_square = x**2
    print('x_square: ', x_square)

def x_pow_y(x,y):
    x_pow_y = x**y
    print('x_pow_y: ', x_pow_y)
    
def fun_qube(z):
    z_qube = z*z*z
    print('z_qube: ', z_qube)
    
def normal_fun():
    print("Normal fun is working at same time...")

Thread(target = fun_square, args=(5,)).start() #args=(x,)
Thread(target = x_pow_y, args=(2,4,)).start() #args=(x,y,)
Thread(target = fun_qube(4)).start() #fun_qube(z)
Thread(target = normal_fun).start()
```

**Example of multiple processing:**

```
from multiprocessing import Process  

def fun_square(x):
    x_square = x**2
    print('x_square: ', x_square) 

def x_pow_y(x,y):
    x_pow_y = x**y
    print('x_pow_y: ', x_pow_y)

def fun_qube(z):
    z_qube = z*z*z
    print('z_qube: ', z_qube)
    
def normal_fun():
    print("Normal fun is working at same time...")


p1 = Process(target = fun_square, args=(5,)).start() #args=(x,)
p2 = Process(target = x_pow_y, args=(2,4,)).start() #args=(x,y,)
p3 = Process(target = fun_qube(5)).start() #fun_qube(z)
p4 = Process(target = normal_fun).start()
```

Answer (score -1):

I might be wrong but:
with this piece of code:

```
def function_sleep():
    time.sleep(5)
```

```
start_time = time.time()
        p1=Process(target=function_sleep)
        p2=Process(target=function_sleep)
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
end_time = time.time()
```

I took the time and I would expect to get 5/6 seconds, while it always takes the double of the argument passed to the function sleep (10 seconds in this case).
What's the matter?

**Sorry guys, as mentioned in the previous comment, the "join()" need to be called.
That's very important!**