# Plot 2 animated plots in Bokeh at the same time?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, bokeh

Is it possible to plot 2 animated plots in Bokeh at the same time?

Is it possible by threading?

thanks,

Yedurag

Comment: can you share what you tried?

Comment: @RafaelBarros: Its a bit complicated. I will try to explain.

Comment: @RafaelBarros   I used the code given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957116/make-2-functions-run-at-the-same-time    Under the func1 I tried to execute line_animated.py example from bokeh and under func2 I tried to run animated.py example from bokeh....Did not work