# Print message while a function is running in Python with AsyncIO

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to create a print function that keeps printing, for example, 'Hello World', while another function (called miner) is running in parallel, and both functions must end at the same time.

[image]

This is for a real-time cost measurer for bitcoin mining that I'm working on.

I found that python as asyncio and tried to use it, however I couldn't get the print function to stop at the same time the miner function ends. The timer function printed once and waited for the miner function.

[image]

```py
import asyncio
import time  
from datetime import datetime
class Test2:  
    async def miner(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        return 0
    async def timer(self):  
        while True:
            print("\n Hello World \n")
            time.sleep(1)

t2 = Test2()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(t2.miner(), t2.timer()))
```

I tried concurrent tasks, but both function does not run in parallel (timer and miner).
Could you show me a way to solve this?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Executing multiple functions simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864859/python-executing-multiple-functions-simultaneously)

Comment: @FaraazKurawle yes exactly what I'm looking for but I was unfortunate. After dozens time of searching I did not find this useful post for some reasons

Answer (score 1):

1. `time.sleep()` is not asynchronous function so `timer` process locks other operations before it ends (but unfortunately it is endless)
2. You may add shared trigger variable to stop `timer` when miner complete

```
import asyncio

class Test2:

    is_ended = False

    async def miner(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        self.is_ended = True
        print("\n I'm done \n")
        return 0

    async def timer(self):  
        while True:
            if self.is_ended:
               print('\n Bye Bye \n')
               break
            print("\n Hello World \n")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

t2 = Test2()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(t2.miner(), t2.timer()))
```

```
 Hello World 


 Hello World 


 Hello World 


 Hello World 


 Hello World 


 I'm done 


 Bye Bye
```

Comment: Thank you so much I found a workaround by using multiple processes ```p = Process(...)```.  If you don't mind, could you tell me what is the difference between using async function vs multiprocesses?

Comment: @SeanWilliam it is better to search for an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435284/multiprocessing-vs-multithreading-vs-asyncio-in-python-3) on this common question in the internet

Comment: Gosh how come when I search for the exact terms these useful posts don't show up at all like yours :(

Comment: @Sean William, can you please share the workaround you found using multiple processes ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use threading:-

```
def func1():
    print('Working')

def func2():
    print("Working")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = func1).start()
    Thread(target = func2).start()
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggesstion. I am now informed of 3 possible solutions: async functions, multiple processes, and threading. Which one would you recommend?

Comment: multithreading programming is all about concurrent execution of different functions. Async programming is about non-blocking execution between functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `multiprocessing` or `threading`

```
from multiprocessing import Process
index=0
def func1():
    global index
    print ('start func1')
    while index< 20:
        index+= 1
    print ('end func1')

def func2():
    global rocket
    print ('start func2')
    while index< 10:
        index+= 1
    print ('end func2')

if __name__=='__main__':
    p1 = Process(target = func1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target = func2)
    p2.start()
```

for treading

```
import threading
x = threading.Thread(target=func1)
y = threading.Thread(target=func1)
```