# Running codes from a list once python

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

Here I have a code, but I want all of this code to run at same time without each waiting for other to finish before the other run.

```
from telegram import *
from telegram.ext import *
import telegram


IDs = [1111,2222,3333,4444]
def start(update,context) -> None:
    while True:
        for user in IDs:
            context.bot.send_message(user,f"hello {user}")
```

Is there a way to send messages to all of these users at once without waiting for it to send to 1111, then 2222,3333 and 4444...?

Comment: Please use code sample

Comment: multiprocessing? One thread by user.

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible code sample. Code you have provided is incomplete and cannot run on its own.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With a huge caveat, yes. You can use [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) *if* the calls to `send_message` can not block the process. This offers concurrency and not parallelism. It would look something like this:

```py
import asyncio


async def main():
    await start(None, None)


async def send_message(user, msg):
    """Has to be non-blocking.

    That is, there has to be a way to instruct the loop to come back and
    check later. For instance, if this is an api that returns a task
    handle, you can call `asyncio.sleep(1)` between every call to check
    the task status. That way the thread can move back to the loop for 1
    second at a time.
    """
    print(f"{msg} {user}")


async def start(update, context) -> None:
    await asyncio.gather(
        *[
            asyncio.create_task(send_message(user, "hello"))
            for user in [1111, 2222, 3333, 4444]
        ]
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

But that may not work in your case at all, if the call to `send_message` waits for a response before continuing.

Here is a good answer to [multiprocessing vs multithreading vs asyncio in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52498068/2081835)

Comment: OP apparently uses a v13.x version of `python-tetlegram-bot`, which is not asyncio based. using `asyncio.create_task` on that doesn't really make sense IISC

Comment: You may well be right that it won't help them. I'll leave the answer since it is still relevant to a more general case. Since you are the maintainer, your answer should most definitely be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

PTB comes with a built-in tool to run I/O bound tasks in a thread pool - [`Dispatcher.run_async`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.11/telegram.ext.dispatcher.html?highlight=dispatcher.run_async#telegram.ext.Dispatcher.run_async). Note that this has nothing to do with `asyncio`. Please see [this wiki page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/v13.x-wiki/wiki/Performance-Optimizations#multithreading) for more details.

Note that the recently published pre-release v20.0a0 introduces `asyncio` to PTB, so starting from v20.x, the [answer given by @theherk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72231895/10606962) will indeed by applicable.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.