# How can I use python multiprocessing in web scraping and attach the scraped text to pandas dataframe faster?

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I'm now web-scraping about 10,000 products from a retail website (e.g., Amazon) everyday to keep track of price history.

Scraping consists of two parts; **firstly**, I collect the "listings" of products where I get the basic information, such as product name, price, id, and *url* of each listing and save that to pandas dataframe. **Secondly**, using each *url* of product, I collect more detailed information about product and attach that one-by-one into the other columns of dataframe. I have no issue in the first part (takes <10 minutes), but it usually takes more than 15 hours to complete the second part.

Below is a sample code. Although the sample code below is not real, the actual code is just prolonged version of it.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
from user_agent import generate_user_agent

df_dic = {
    "product_name": ['product1','product2','product3','product4','product5'],
    "product_price": ['500','800','300','700','1000'],
    "product_id": ['1000','1001','1002','1003','1004'],
    "product_url": ['url1','url2','url3','url4','url5'],
    
}

# df is the data scraped from the first part
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dic) 

df['product_chracter1'] = ""
df['product_chracter2'] = ""
df['product_chracter3'] = ""
df['product_chracter4'] = ""
df['product_chracter5'] = ""

df['product_chracter6'] = ""
df['product_chracter7'] = ""
df['product_chracter8'] = ""
df['product_chracter9'] = ""
df['product_chracter10'] = ""


# Below is the beginning of the second part where detailed product characteristics (more than 50) are attached to dataframe 

for i_url in df['product_url']:
    try:
        product_id = df['product_id'].loc[df['prouct_url']==i_url]         
        params = {'productSeq': product_id}        
        headers = {'User-Agent': generate_user_agent(device_type='smartphone', navigator='chrome')}
        
        baseline_url = r'https://www.something.com'
        html = requests.post(baseline_url, headers = headers, params = params).text
        time.sleep(0.3)
        df['product_chracter1'].loc[df['prouct_url']==i_url]     = re.findall(r'var product_chracter1 = "(.+?)";', html)[0]
        df['product_chracter2'].loc[df['prouct_url']==i_url]     = re.findall(r'var product_chracter2 = "(.+?)";', html)[0]
        df['product_chracter3'].loc[df['prouct_url']==i_url]     = re.findall(r'var product_chracter3 = "(.+?)";', html)[0]
        df['product_chracter4'].loc[df['prouct_url']==i_url]     = re.findall(r'var product_chracter4 = "(.+?)";', html)[0]
        df['product_chracter5'].loc[df['prouct_url']==i_url]     = re.findall(r'var product_chracter5 = "(.+?)";', html)[0]

        baseline_url_2 = r'https://www.something_2.com'
        html = requests.post(baseline_url_2, headers = headers, params = params).text
        time.sleep(0.3)
        df['product_chracter6'].loc[df['prouct_url']==i_url]     = re.findall(r'var product_chracter6 = "(.+?)";', html)[0]
        df['product_chracter7'].loc[df['prouct_url']==i_url]     = re.findall(r'var product_chracter7 = "(.+?)";', html)[0]
        df['product_chracter8'].loc[df['prouct_url']==i_url]     = re.findall(r'var product_chracter8 = "(.+?)";', html)[0]
        df['product_chracter9'].loc[df['prouct_url']==i_url]     = re.findall(r'var product_chracter9 = "(.+?)";', html)[0]
        df['product_chracter10'].loc[df['prouct_url']==i_url]    = re.findall(r'var product_chracter10 = "(.+?)";', html)[0]

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Some error happened at {i_url}")
        print(e)
        continue

filename = 'site_date'
df.to_pickle(f'{filename}.pkl')
```

I used `try` and `except` as there exist some products that are sold while scraping or do not show some characteristics, thus, causes error. I'm only using `requests.get` and `requests.post`, not `selenium`. My question is, how I can use `multiprocessing` in python and make my code run faster? I read that `ThreadPoolExecutor` from the `concurrent.futures` library can help, but really do not have any knowledge how I can implement that in my case.

Any help, different approach, and any comments would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and consideration for reading this.

**Updated: 2022-07-02**

Thanks to @GohKohHan's comment, I was able to apply multiprocessing into my code and it takes almost 1/`max_workers` of the time run with the previous code. I know my code is not perfect and a lot of people here are super masters at `python`, so I hope you to point out ***any*** mistakes or things that need to be improved from the following code.

```py
import requests,re
import time
import pandas as pd
from user_agent import generate_user_agent
import concurrent.futures


start_time = time.time
urls = df['product_url']
def return_dataframe(i_url):
    try:
        unique = []  
        product_chracter1=[];  product_chracter6=[]
        product_chracter2=[];  product_chracter7=[]
        product_chracter3=[];  product_chracter8=[]
        product_chracter4=[];  product_chracter9=[]
        product_chracter5=[];  product_chracter10=[]

        product_id = df['product_id'].loc[df['prouct_url']==i_url]         
        params = {'productSeq': product_id}        
        headers = {'User-Agent':generate_user_agent(device_type='smartphone', navigator='chrome')}
        
        unique.append(i_url)
        baseline_url = r'https://www.something.com'
        html = requests.post(baseline_url, headers = headers, params = params).text
        time.sleep(0.3)
        product_chracter1.append(re.findall(r'var product_chracter1 = "(.+?)";', html)[0])
        product_chracter2.append(re.findall(r'var product_chracter2 = "(.+?)";', html)[0])
        product_chracter3.append(re.findall(r'var product_chracter3 = "(.+?)";', html)[0])
        product_chracter4.append(re.findall(r'var product_chracter4 = "(.+?)";', html)[0])
        product_chracter5.append(re.findall(r'var product_chracter5 = "(.+?)";', html)[0])

        baseline_url_2 = r'https://www.something_2.com'
        html = requests.post(baseline_url_2, headers = headers, params = params).text
        time.sleep(0.3)
        product_chracter6.append(re.findall(r'var product_chracter6 = "(.+?)";', html)[0])
        product_chracter7.append(re.findall(r'var product_chracter7 = "(.+?)";', html)[0])
        product_chracter8.append(re.findall(r'var product_chracter8 = "(.+?)";', html)[0])
        product_chracter9.append(re.findall(r'var product_chracter9 = "(.+?)";', html)[0])
        product_chracter10.append(re.findall(r'var product_chracter10 = "(.+?)";', html)[0])
       
        i_df_detailed = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(unique, product_chracter1, product_chracter2, product_chracter3, 
                      product_chracter4, product_chracter5, product_chracter6,
                      product_chracter7, product_chracter8, product_chracter9,
                      product_chracter10)),
                      columns = ['unique', 'product_chracter1', 'product_chracter2', 'product_chracter3',
                       'product_chracter4', 'product_chracter5', 'product_chracter6',
                       'product_chracter7', 'product_chracter8', 'product_chracter9',
                       'product_chracter10'])

        return i_df_detailed

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Some error happened at {i_url}")
        print(e)
        continue

detailed_agg = []
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:    
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(return_dataframe, i_url): i_url for i_url in urls}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        try:
            detailed_agg.append(future.result())
        except Exception as exc:
            print('generated an exception: %s' % (exc))

 

df_detailed = pd.concat(detailed_agg)
df_agg = pd.merge(df, df_detailed, how='left', left_on=['product_url'], right_on=['unique'])

# How long did it take?
print("---  %.1f minutes ---" % (int(time.time() - start_time)/60))
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Best way to this would be asynchronous programming rather than multiprocessing imo

Comment: Since speed is important here, I suggest not to loop through a data frame. You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/12937384) for explanation.

Comment: Hi @GohKokHan, I looked over [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/55557758#55557758)  you referred to, but it seems that it is inevitable for me to loop over rows to extract the unique url of each product. And I am using neither `iterrows` nor `itertuples`. Please let me know if I'm thinking wrong?

Comment: @Dandytomato, you can store the _product_url_ in a **list** instead of **df**. Looping through **list** is more efficient, you can **append** the scraped data to the **list** and convert the **list** to **df** once you have finished scraped everything.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't drastically change the time spent...I really need to use multiprocessing. I'm now trying `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`, but it seems difficult more than what I can afford with my ability.

Comment: How big is the `df_dict`? Would you be okay with using asyncio and multiprocessing at the same time? Also, how big does the dataframe get before beginning the second part?

Comment: @Charchit (i) `df_dict` is about `12000 x 100` sized dataframe. (ii) I'm actually not that knowledgeable to understand difference between asyncio and multiprocessing. All I know is that my school has high performance computer resources (e.g., big red) and multiprocessing can quicken my job. (iii) `df_dict` gets about `12000 x 150` sized dataframe.

Comment: @Charchit, I'm not sure what you mean by `asynchronous programming` is, (are you saying `grequests`? let me know if I'm wrong) but I updated my code and it uses `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`. Is that `asynchronous programming`  or `multiprocessing`?

Comment: @Dandytomato, it's neither. It's multithreading. Grequests is an example of asynchrounous library, but for your use case I would recommend using `trio` and `httpx`. Both have a very good documentation and `httpx` is most similar to requests. On the other hand, you could also use `asyncio` with `aiohttp`, they are more popular and you are likely to get more help regarding specific problems online. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435284/multiprocessing-vs-multithreading-vs-asyncio-in-python-3) thread for differences between multithreading and async.