# What is the alternative of multiprocessing to scrape multiple URLs at once?

Tags: python, web-scraping

As I mentioned that I am using [Python multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) to scrape millions of records where I spawn 30-50 processes at once that execute a certain method. What I found is that is it not resource friendly; spawning multiple `python` processes at once. What are efficient and resource-friendly alternatives are provided by modern python versions other than threading?

Comment: You can look at `asyncio` module.

Comment: @AndrejKesely is it good for scraping millions of records and I/O operations like storing in Database?

Comment: I don't know the specifics but `asyncio` (`aiohttp` especially) is more resource friendly - it doesn't spawn new process with its own python interpreter...

Comment: What's wrong with threading, btw? There aren't _that_ many [different concurrency model options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435284/multiprocessing-vs-multithreading-vs-asyncio-in-python-3) (for running on a single computer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiprocessing vs multithreading vs asyncio in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435284/multiprocessing-vs-multithreading-vs-asyncio-in-python-3)

Comment: @AndrejKesely did you ever use aiohttp for hundred thousands urls? If so, what was the ram usage when loading the url list?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire Never used it in that scale. But I imagine the RAM usage won't be big: not to store anything in memory (e.g. to not load the URLs into a list - but read them lazily from DB for example, use a working queue etc.). Also not store the results from scraping in memory (again, store it into DB as soon as possible).