# Running multiple functions that make HTTP requests in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

I'm working on a script that autonomously scrapes historical data from several websites and saves them to the same excel file for each past date that's within a specified date range. Each individual function accesses several webpages from a different website, formats the data, and writes it to the file on separate sheets. Because I am continuously making requests on these sites, I make sure that I add ample sleep time between requests. Instead of running these functions one after another, is there a way that I could run them together?

I want to make one request with Function 1, then make one request with Function 2, and so on until all functions have made one request. After all functions have made a request, I would like it to loop back and complete the second request within each function (and so on) until all requests for a given date are complete. Doing this would allow the same amount of sleep time between requests on each website while decreasing the time the code would take to run by a large amount. One point to note is that each function makes a slightly different number of HTTP requests. For instance, Function 1 may make 10 requests on a given date while Function 2 makes 8 requests, Function 3 makes 8, Function 4 makes 7, and Function 5 makes 10.

I've read into this topic and have read about multithreading, but I am unsure how to apply this to my specific scenario. If there is no way to do this, I could run each function as its own code and run them at the same time, but then I would have to concatenate five different excel files for each date, which is why I am trying to do it this way.

```
start_date = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
end_date = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
idx = pd.date_range(start_date,end_date)
date_range = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in idx]
max_retries_min_sleeptime = 300
max_retries_max_sleeptime = 600
min_sleeptime = 150
max_sleeptime = 250
for date in date_range:
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Daily Data -' + date + '.xlsx')
    Function1()
    Function2()
    Function3()
    Function4()
    Function5()
    writer.save()
    print('Date Complete: ' + date)
    time.sleep(random.randrange(min_sleeptime,max_sleeptime,1))
```

Comment: check out `aiohttp` https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 1):

Using Python3.6

Here is a minimal example of concurrent requests with `aiohttp` to get you started ([docs](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)). This example runs 3 `downloader`'s at the same time, appending the `rsp` to responses. I believe you will be able to adapt this idea to your problem.

```
import asyncio

from aiohttp.client import ClientSession


async def downloader(session, iter_url, responses):
    while True:
        try:
            url = next(iter_url)
        except StopIteration:
            return
        rsp = await session.get(url)
        if not rsp.status == 200:
            continue  # < - Or raise error
        responses.append(rsp)


async def run(urls, responses):
    with ClientSession() as session:
        iter_url = iter(urls)
        await asyncio.gather(*[downloader(session, iter_url, responses) for _ in range(3)])


urls = [
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python',
    'https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/',
    'https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html'
]

responses = []

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run(urls, responses))
```

---

**Result:**

```
>>> responses
[<ClientResponse(https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) [200 OK]>
<CIMultiDictProxy('Server': 'nginx', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Last-Modified': 'Sun, 28 Jan 2018 05:08:54 GMT', 'ETag': '"5a6d5ae6-6eae"', 'X-Clacks-Overhead': 'GNU Terry Pratchett', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=315360000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'Via': '1.1 varnish', 'Fastly-Debug-Digest': '79eb68156ce083411371cd4dbd0cb190201edfeb12e5d1a8a1e273cc2c8d0e41', 'Content-Length': '28334', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Date': 'Sun, 28 Jan 2018 23:48:17 GMT', 'Via': '1.1 varnish', 'Age': '66775', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'X-Served-By': 'cache-iad2140-IAD, cache-mel6520-MEL', 'X-Cache': 'HIT, HIT', 'X-Cache-Hits': '1, 1', 'X-Timer': 'S1517183297.337465,VS0,VE1')>
, <ClientResponse(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [200 OK]>
<CIMultiDictProxy('Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-Request-Guid': '3fb98f74-2a89-497d-8d43-322f9a202775', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=15552000', 'Content-Length': '23775', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Date': 'Sun, 28 Jan 2018 23:48:17 GMT', 'Via': '1.1 varnish', 'Age': '0', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'X-Served-By': 'cache-mel6520-MEL', 'X-Cache': 'MISS', 'X-Cache-Hits': '0', 'X-Timer': 'S1517183297.107658,VS0,VE265', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding,Fastly-SSL', 'X-DNS-Prefetch-Control': 'off', 'Set-Cookie': 'prov=8edb36d8-8c63-bdd5-8d56-19bf14916c93; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly', 'Cache-Control': 'private')>
, <ClientResponse(https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) [200 OK]>
<CIMultiDictProxy('Server': 'nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)', 'Date': 'Sun, 28 Jan 2018 23:48:18 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Last-Modified': 'Wed, 17 Jan 2018 08:45:22 GMT', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'ETag': 'W/"5a5f0d22-578a"', 'X-Subdomain-TryFiles': 'True', 'X-Served': 'Nginx', 'X-Deity': 'web01', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip')>
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example to demonstrate how to use `concurrent.futures` for parallel processing. This does not include the actual scraping logic as you can add it yourself, if needed, but demonstrates the pattern to follow:

```
from concurrent import futures
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def scrape_func(*args, **kwargs):
    """ Stub function to use with futures - your scraping logic """
    print("Do something in parallel")
    return "result scraped"

def main():
    start_date = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    end_date = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    idx = pd.date_range(start_date,end_date)
    date_range = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in idx]
    max_retries_min_sleeptime = 300
    max_retries_max_sleeptime = 600
    min_sleeptime = 150
    max_sleeptime = 250

    # The important part - concurrent futures 
    # - set number of workers as the number of jobs to process

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(len(date_range)) as executor:
        # Use list jobs for concurrent futures
        # Use list scraped_results for results
        jobs = []
        scraped_results = []

        for date in date_range:
            # Pass some keyword arguments if needed - per job    
            kw = {"some_param": "value"}

            # Here we iterate 'number of dates' times, could be different
            # We're adding scrape_func, could be different function per call
            jobs.append(executor.submit(scrape_func, **kw))

        # Once parallell processing is complete, iterate over results
        for job in futures.as_completed(jobs):
            # Read result from future
            scraped_result = job.result()
            # Append to the list of results
            scraped_results.append(scraped_result)

        # Iterate over results scraped and do whatever is needed
        for result is scraped_results:
            print("Do something with me {}".format(result))


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

As mentioned, this is just to demonstrate the pattern to follow, the rest should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses guys! As it turns out a pretty simple block of code from this other question ([Make 2 functions run at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957116/make-2-functions-run-at-the-same-time)) seems to do what I want.

```
import threading
from threading import Thread

def func1():
    print 'Working'

def func2():
    print 'Working'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = func1).start()
    Thread(target = func2).start()
```

Comment: If threading solves your problem, do it. You might re-visit these examples, if you out grow your current solution.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you mean by outgrow my solution? Is threading a more CPU intensive process or is it only suitable for a small number or functions to be efficient or something? I'm new to this specific concept so I'm learning as I go.

Comment: I can't give that question justice. The answer is moderately nuanced. This  talk by Raymond Hettinger might be a good start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv25Dwe84g0

Comment: Thank you for this, I found it quite interesting and informative. I'm going to implement the code with threading and see how it goes going forward.