# Running a program with music in Replit (Python)

Tags: python, audio

I found the library for music in replit python -- `from replit import audio`. However, it only works by itself. That is, it cannot run code along with it.

It runs like this:

```
audio.play_file("music.mp3")
time.sleep(100)
```

However, the `sleep` command, which is required for it to run (otherwise it'll "skip" the command as it runs for 0 seconds), means that no code can be run during this time. I tried to use `thread` but it returns an error instead when I put it in a function and [call it with thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957116/make-2-functions-run-at-the-same-time).

Working code (music only):

```
from replit import audio
import time

audio.play_file("tlc.mp3")
time.sleep(100)
```

Error code:

```
from replit import audio
import time
from threading import Thread

def func1():
    audio.play_file("tlc.mp3")
    time.sleep(100)

def func2():
    print('working.')
    # do other things I want to do

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = func1).start()
    Thread(target = func2).start()
```

It simply prints "working." with half a page of error message and no music appears. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Some background info: I want to make a console-based game with music in the background but cannot get it to work.

Comment: [replit forum post with simliar error message](https://replit.com/talk/ask/Replit-audio-not-working/122298) possibly helpful or related

Comment: Maybe have a look at [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) that is able to run audio and code in parallel.

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken The correct answer there is that the file is too short but my file is 234 seconds long and I'm only playing the first 100.

Comment: good point @CELLSecret, other posts on that forum mention [the music files may be to large to play immediately, hence the time out.](https://replit.com/talk/ask/Audio-was-not-created-within-2-seconds/116016) and other issues. It may be helpful to search that forum. or possibly it will be answered here.

Comment: @mozway I tried, but it worked for me (without errors) just *there's no music* either :(