# How do you load multiple chrome browsers with Kameleo and Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, kameleo

I want to load multiple chrome browsers using Kameleo's Selenium. Can someone give me some example code to show how it’s done? The selenium portion of my code is:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('kameleo:profileId', profile.id)
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor=f'{kameleoBaseUrl}/webdriver',
        options=options
    )

    driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLTp9ni9mKc&t=1s')
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Play']").click()
```

Comment: I see that you are not just trying to make Selenium work but you are experimenting with Kameleo as well. I think Kameleo is a powerful tool when it comes to automating several browser instances with different IP address and device fingerprint thank to their Selenium Stealth WebDriver.
I would like to raise your attention on this [example](https://github.com/kameleo-io/local-api-examples/blob/master/python/connect_to_selenium/app.py)
Simply duplicate from line 16 to line 45 and you will have 2 separate browsers. Let me know if you need some more help and then I'll write a short POC in answer

Comment: I would like the browsers to open up at the same time is this possible?

Comment: I have created a code snippet below in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71857420/4080226). Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are trying to operate with [Kameleo's](https://kameleo.io/learn-more/automation/) Selenium Stealth Driver from your python code. And you are trying to perform the same action parallelly from 2 browsers. Here I created a code snippet that will work by using `threading`

```
from kameleo.local_api_client.kameleo_local_api_client import KameleoLocalApiClient
from kameleo.local_api_client.builder_for_create_profile import BuilderForCreateProfile
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from threading import Thread

kameleo_port = 5050
client = KameleoLocalApiClient(f'http://localhost:{kameleo_port}')


def run_browser():
    base_profiles = client.search_base_profiles(
        device_type='desktop',
        browser_product='chrome'
    )

    # This line may be added as well after .set_recommended_defaults() \ line:
    # .set_proxy('socks5', Server(host='<proxy_host>', port=1080, id='<username>', secret='<password>')) \
    create_profile_request = BuilderForCreateProfile \
        .for_base_profile(base_profiles[0].id) \
        .set_recommended_defaults() \
        .build()

    profile = client.create_profile(body=create_profile_request)

    client.start_profile(profile.id)

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option("kameleo:profileId", profile.id)
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor=f'http://localhost:{kameleo_port}/webdriver',
        options=options
    )

    driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLTp9ni9mKc&t=1s')
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Play']").click()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=run_browser).start()
    Thread(target=run_browser).start()
```

This code is forcing Kameleo through its [Local API](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/kameleo-team/kameleo-local-api/) to start 2 browsers parallelly. Each of these browsers is started in an isolated environment, so their browser fingerprint is different, so websites will see them as 2 different devices. Once the browsers are started they can be controlled with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) commands.

Consider setting up a proxy for the virtual browser profile builder

```
.set_proxy('socks5', Server(host='<proxy_host>', port=1080, id='<username>', secret='<password>')) \
```

This will help you to have different IP address for each browsers started by Kameleo.

I used [this tutorial](https://help.kameleo.io/hc/en-us/articles/4418166326417-Getting-started-with-Kameleo-Automation) to get started with Kameleo and used my Python knowledge for browser automation. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2957131/4080226) you can find more info about running functions at the same time in Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do the same things multiple time, just use the loop. For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('kameleo:profileId', profile.id)
n=2 # set the number of browsers
for i in range(2):
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor=f'{kameleoBaseUrl}/webdriver',
    options=options)
    url='https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNjIwNzg5NzQtNzRlYS00YzFmLWJiNTUtOTM2MGEwY2FjOGJlIiwidCI6ImE3NWRkYWZlLWQ2MmYtNGIxOS04NThhLTllYzFhYjI1NDdkNCIsImMiOjl9'
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Play']").click()
```

Comment: Didn’t work only one screen loads