# What threading module should I use to prevent disk IO from blocking network IO?

Tags: python, multithreading, io, blocking, nonblocking

I have a Python application that, to be brief, receives data from a remote server, processes it, responds to the server, and occasionally saves the processed data to disk. The problem I've encountered is that there is a *lot* of data to write, and the save process can take upwards of half a minute. This is apparently a blocking operation, so the network IO is stalled during this time. I'd like to be able to make the save operation take place in the background, so-to-speak, so that the application can continue to communicate with the server reasonably quickly.

I know that I probably need some kind of threading module to accomplish this, but I can't tell what the differences are between `thread`, `threading`, `multiprocessing`, and the various other options. Does anybody know what I'm looking for?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629680/deciding-between-subprocess-multiprocessing-and-thread-in-python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're I/O bound, then use the `threading` module.

You should almost never need to use `thread`, it's a low-level interface; the `threading` module is a high-level interface wrapper for `thread`.

The `multiprocessing` module is different from the threading module, `multiprocessing` uses multiple subprocesses to execute a task; `multiprocessing` just happens to use the same interface as `threading` to reduce learning curve. `multiprocessing` is typically used when you have CPU bound calculation, and need to avoid the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) in a multicore CPU.

A somewhat more esoteric alternative to multi-threading is asynchronous I/O using `asyncore` module. Another options includes Stackless Python and Twisted.

Comment: (Sorry for the edit) Just wanted to point out that this answer is not entirely accurate with respect to disk I/O in particular.

Asynchronous disk I/O is different from nonblocking: blocking refers to a system call that does not have the answer and is guaranteed to take time--in other words, network and piped I/O.  However, when reading from disk, I/O will never "block": it might be slow.

asyncore and twisted focus on nonblocking I/O so cannot help in this situation. Threads *should* help, but I have been bitten by the GIL with disk I/O...

Feel free to correct me on this.