# python - advise library like requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests

Advise useful python library for work with http with cookies and different methods (GET, POST, etc) like requests.

The main criterions is useful and simplicity. Would very much like to work with library asynchronously by gevent or eventlet.

UPD:
I dont want to use requests because it is not work asynchronously:
[how enable requests async mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501663/how-enable-requests-async-mode)

UPD2:
In requests refused urllib2 to urllib3. I think to use urllib2 is bad way.
This is not to mention the fact that it is useful.

Answer (score 2):

Requests fully support asynchronous requests.

Here's more information in the docs:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#asynchronous-requests

Answer (score 0):

**[Eventlet](http://eventlet.net/doc/examples.html)** and **[Gevent](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html)** are both compatible with **[urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)** and **[cookielib](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html)**, which both depend on the automatically patched socket module and should be able to work with different request methods and cookies.

With **eventlet**, you only need:

```
import eventlet
from eventlet.green import urllib2
import cookielib
```

and with **gevent**, you only need:

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_socket()
import urllib2, cookielib
```

Those solutions will make both **urllib2** and **cookielib** thread-safe.

Comment: Sorry, but urllib2 and cookielib so hard for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [cookielib](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html)?

Comment: Yes, I looked this when only start finding some libraries for http. But, I refused this because it is so hard for using versus requests.