# create asynchronous requests on fly using greqeusts

Tags: python, asynchronous, grequests

So I know that you could use `grequests` create multiple requests and use `map` to process them at the same time. But how do you create some requests on the fly while some requests sent have not returned a response yet? I don't want to use multiprocessing or multithreading,is there a way to use grequests to realize it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the regular requests library for this. A call to `res = requests.get(...)` is asynchronous anyway, it will not block until you call something like "res.content". Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I believe request itself is blocking. [Python Requests non-blocking? duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245989/python-requests-non-blocking)