# Problems with hooks using Requests Python package

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, request, typeerror

I'm using the module `requests` and I recieved this message when I started using hooks.

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 321, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 426, in send
r = dispatch_hook('response', hooks, r, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/hooks.py", line 41, in dispatch_hook
_hook_data = hook(hook_data, **kwargs)
TypeError: hook() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verify'
```

And this is my code (simplified):

```
import requests
def hook(r):
     print r.json()

r = requests.get("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blue%20angels&rpp=5", hooks=dict(response=hook))
```

Comment: I think you need to check what the server is sending you.

Comment: The same code without hooks work fine:

`import requests`
`r = requests.get("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blue%20angels&rpp=5")`
`print r.json()`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [the requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), your hook function doesnt need to take any keyword arguments, but according [to the source code on github](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/hooks.py), the event dispatcher may pass on kwargs to your hook function.  Seems like incomplete documentation to me.  Redefine your method as:

```
def hook(r, **kwargs):
    # ...
```