# AttributeError using hooks in Requests Python package

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, attributeerror

I am sending requests and receiving their response objects into a hooked function.
Sometimes, I'm sending a new request out of that same function, which in turns calls the function that sends requests (with a new thread for each request).

That creates the following exception in the Requests module itself:

```
Exception in thread Thread-103:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/api.py", line 272, in thread_func
    r = self.session.post(url, data=params, headers=headers, timeout=60, hooks=dict(response=self.http_callback))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 425, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 383, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 494, in send
    if r.history:
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'history'
```

I find that very strange. Do you know what might be happening?

Note: I looked at this question but my problem is different: [Problems with hooks using Requests Python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594015/problems-with-hooks-using-requests-python-package)

Comment: You've returned a boolean where `requests` expected a response object. Without your code however, nothing more meaningful can be stated.

Comment: Where is `self.http_callback` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line before the exception point reads:

```
r = dispatch_hook('response', hooks, r, **kwargs)
```

Your hook returned a boolean, while it *should* return a response object. A boolean doesn't have a `history` attribute, while a response object would.

Alternatively, return `None` if you did not mean to alter the response.

From the [event hooks documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#event-hooks):

> If the callback function returns a value, it is assumed that it is to replace the data that was passed in. If the function doesn’t return anything, nothing else is effected.

The value passed in for the `response` hook is the response object; the replacement value should be a response object *too*.

**Fix your hook.** From your traceback we can see that you passed in `self.http_callback` as the hook, if you were wondering where to look.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not sure our documentation is correct in that respect anymore. I'll have to check.

Comment: @sigmavirus24: the current [implementation of hooks](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/hooks.py) looks like it still fits the documentation. Return `None` and nothing is done to the initial value passed in, return something and it replaces that value.

Comment: @sigmavirus24: the only thing that changed with hooks (since the last time Kenneth refactored hooks in Dec 2012) is the additional support to pass in arbitrary keyword arguments from the original `.get()`, `.post()`, etc. calls to registered hooks. And that was in [February 2013](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/commit/d0285fac4203e8cfed6b5ceeb96b2646076e745d#diff-ab3246c102b4e3c7381cf4d1ea4b2bea)..

Comment: Well, the exception comes from the Requests code itself. I looked at it a bit deeper and it seems like Requests uses the `return` of my callback function and searches it for a `history` attribute. In some cases my function returns a `bool`, which is not necessary so I'm removing that and it should fix the problem. However it might be good to add some error handling for that in Requests, no?

Comment: I told you why the exception comes from within `requests`: because your hook violates the documented return value it expected. When library code throws an exception, you always need to verify that you didn't pass it invalid data.