# In what way is grequests asynchronous?

Tags: python, python-requests, gevent, grequests

I've been using the python requests library for some time, and recently had a need to make a request asynchronously, meaning I would like to send off the HTTP request, have my main thread continue to execute, and have a callback called when the request returns.

Naturally, I was lead to the grequests library (https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests), but i'm confused about the behavior. For example:

```
import grequests

def print_res(res):
    from pprint import pprint
    pprint (vars(res))

req = grequests.get('http://www.codehenge.net/blog', hooks=dict(response=print_res))
res = grequests.map([req])

for i in range(10):
    print i
```

The above code will produce the following output:

```
<...large HTTP response output...>

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

The grequests.map() call obviously blocks until the HTTP response is available. It seems likely I misunderstood the 'asynchronous' behavior here, and the grequests library is just for performing multiple HTTP requests concurrently and sending all responses to a single callback. Is this accurate?

Comment: Not sure, but could you not just use the built-in `urllib` module and run it in a background thread with the `thread` module?

Comment: I think i may have to do just that. I was just confused, and want to verify the expected behavior.

Comment: Sure. I just tend to stick with built-ins where possible to maximize portability.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`.map()` is meant to run retrieval of several URLs in parallel, and will indeed wait for these tasks to complete (`gevent.joinall(jobs)`) is called).

Use `.send()` instead to spawn jobs, using a [`Pool` instance](http://www.gevent.org/api/gevent.pool.html#gevent.pool.Pool):

```
req = grequests.get('http://www.codehenge.net/blog', hooks=dict(response=print_res))
job = grequests.send(req, grequests.Pool(1))

for i in range(10):
    print i
```

Without the pool the `.send()` call will block still, but only for the `gevent.spawn()` call it executes.

Comment: @martijn pieters Can you give a sample with post. Not able to get it work with post calls

Comment: @Avinash: just use `grequests.post()` instead? As far as `grequests` is concerned, there is no difference between the various request methods.

Comment: What does .pool() actually do? I did not understand the documentation.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to use `grequests` you can just implement requests with callbacks using `requests` + the `threading` module from the standard library. It's actually really easy, and if all you want to do is send requests with callbacks the API is nicer than the one provided by `grequests`.

```
from threading import Thread

from requests import get, post, put, patch, delete, options, head



request_methods = {
    'get': get,
    'post': post,
    'put': put,
    'patch': patch,
    'delete': delete,
    'options': options,
    'head': head,
}


def async_request(method, *args, callback=None, timeout=15, **kwargs):
    """Makes request on a different thread, and optionally passes response to a
    `callback` function when request returns.
    """
    method = request_methods[method.lower()]
    if callback:
        def callback_with_args(response, *args, **kwargs):
            callback(response)
        kwargs['hooks'] = {'response': callback_with_args}
    kwargs['timeout'] = timeout
    thread = Thread(target=method, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    thread.start()
```

You can verify that it works like an AJAX calls in JS: you send a request on another thread, do some stuff on the main thread, and when the request returns you invoke a callback. This callback just prints out the response content.

```
async_request('get', 'http://httpbin.org/anything', callback=lambda r: print(r.json()))
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of requests and then send them with `.imap`:

```
event_list = [grequests.get(url_viol_card, params={"viol": i},
              session=session) for i in print_ev_list]
for r in grequests.imap(event_list, size=5):
    print(r.request.url)
```

- `session` is `requests.Session()` object (optional)
- `size=5` send 5 requests simultaneously: as soon as one of them is completed the next one is sent
- In this example when any request (unordered) is completed its url is printed