# How to make asynchronous HTTP POST requests

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this program which runs in a loop with `pythoncom.PumpMessages()`.
While this program runs, it takes input and stores it iternally.
When the input reaches a certain lenght, I'd like to send a HTTP POST request asynchronously to a database I have in the cloud so the program doesn't stop taking input while the request is sent. I do not need the request from the server, although it would be nice.

Is this possible? I'm having a hard time figuring this out. Right now it does it synchronously.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done if you use python requests library to send post requests. 
It has been answered here.
[Asynchronous Requests with Python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests)
The example is for "GET" request but you can easily do post request as well.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript works on any browser without added libraries.
This is great for loading parts of a page without stalling the UI, but use another method (e.g. server or NodeJS) if sending many requests (e.g. >100).

```
<p id="demo">Customer info will be listed here...</p>

<script>
function showCustomer(str) {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "yourFile.php?queryVariable="+str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_xmlhttprequest_database

GET: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_xmlhttprequest_first

More here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_http.asp