# Python async webservice call

Tags: python, web-services, asynchronous, web, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry module in which python code running. Now I have to call web services asynchronously from it. But when i write code and execute gives an error like

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "async_ws.py", line 3, in <module>
    from requests import async
ImportError: cannot import name async
```

my code is like

```
import json
import requests
from requests import async

urls = [
    'http://python-requests.org',
    'http://httpbin.org',
    'http://python-guide.org',
    'http://kennethreitz.com'
]

rs = [async.get(u) for u in urls]
async.map(rs)
```

pls help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronous Requests with Python requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests)

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't look like either of the most common async libraries for python requests, which are `grequests` (using gevent) and `requests-futures`. I would see if you can install requests-futures from https://github.com/ross/requests-futures (including the concurrent.futures backported from python 3, if you are running python 2).

Comment: The code looks like it's using the [requests library async module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.6/user/advanced/#asynchronous-requests)