# fastest way to Test 100+ Million Domains

Tags: php, jquery, python, mysql, ajax

I have 100+ Million domains in my MySQL db and i want to check each domain if it is active or not. i did it using PHP CURL, i execute the script and if the response returns i mark the domain as active and if it doesn't return the response i mark it inactive.

here is the code:

```
function isDomainAvailable(){
    $domain = "http://www.".$this->input->post('url');
    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    $this->load->model('urls');
    if(!filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
           $this->urls->setActive($id,0);
           errorMessage('Invalid url');
    }

    $curlInit = curl_init($domain);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    $response = curl_exec($curlInit);
    curl_close($curlInit);
    if ($response){
        $this->urls->setActive($id,1);
        successMessage('url is active');
    }
    $this->urls->setActive($id,0);
    errorMessage('url is not active');
}
```

and i am running this script with a synchronous AJAX calls so that it keep updating the UI to make sure the script is running and which record it is currently at:

here is the JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#startCheck").click(function(){
    pages = 2313744;
    for(i=1;i<=pages;i++){
        url = "<?php echo base_url() ?>main/getDomains/"+i+"/1";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:url,
            data: $("#form").serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout:30000,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.data){
                    $(".recordstable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                    $.each(data.data, function(i,v) {
                        row = '<tr>';
                        row += '<td>'+v.id+'</td>';
                        row += '<td>'+v.url+'</td>';
                        row += '<td class="active'+v.id+'">';
                        row += '<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/loading.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Loading"></td>';
                        row += '</tr>';
                        $('.recordstable tr:last').after(row);


                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url:'<?php echo base_url() ?>main/isDomainAvailable',
                                    data: {url:v.url,id:v.id},
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    timeout:10000,
                                    async: false,
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        if(data.success){
                                            $('.active'+v.id).html('<span class="label label-success">Yes</span>');
                                        }else{
                                            $('.active'+v.id).html('<span class="label label-danger">No</span>');
                                        }
                                    },
                                    error:function(data){
                                        $('.active'+v.id).html('<span class="label label-warning">Failed</span>');
                                        //alert("something went wrong, please try again.");
                                        $(".loader").hide();
                                    }
                                });





                    });
                }
            },
            error:function(data){
                alert("something went wrong, please try again.");
                $(".loader").hide();
            }
        });
        //break;
    }
    return false;
});

});
```

first the script is running a for loop on urls, each request on url returns 50 domains and when the data returns another AJAX call send request to the script i have posted above which test the domain and return response in success or failure and then the script update the UI to show it is done checking, here is the screen shot of the webpage testing the domains

[image]

the problem with this script is that is running very slow as it tested only 4000 domains in last 10hours
i need a fastest way to test the domains
PHP isnt required for this.
if there is any solution available for Python please share

Comment: threading might be something for you to look into. 4000 in 10 hours could possibly turn into 4000 * 10 in 10 hours if you are using 10 threads.

Comment: yea thats what i was planning to do... do u think the code can be optimized in any way or is it just fine?

Comment: With python, you can use [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) for this. Examples in this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests

Comment: can u give an example on threading?

Comment: The linked Python answer is awesome.

Comment: Don't do it in Javascript; use something e.g. Python on the server and periodically poll an endpoint using Javascript.

Comment: can u help me run a python script on a server? like if i run it, its keep running even if i close my pc

Answer (score 0):

Why JavaScript and AJAX?  Do it all in PHP.

Instead of `if (!$response)` use

```
if (curl_errno($curlInit)){
  errorMessage(curl_error($curlInit));
}
```

Comment: i used javascript just to keep the UI updated that the test is running and to see which domains it is currently testing

Comment: You can do that by using ob_start and ob_flush.  You could write results status to a text file then periodically look at the the text file.