# Does unirest support python3?

Tags: python-3.x, unirest

Does unirest support python3? I have googled and zero information comes up. Even in [the unirest documentation](http://unirest.io/python.html) it does not say it is 2.x only which leads me to believe it supports both 3.x and 2.x. However the install fails with 3.4 and succeeds with 2.7. See below.

```
nkltss:~/dev$ mkvirtualenv mashape -p /usr/bin/python3
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in mashape/bin/python3
Also creating executable in mashape/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.


(mashape)nkltss:~/dev$ pip install unirest
Downloading/unpacking unirest
  Downloading Unirest-1.1.6.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/home/nick/.virtualenvs/mashape/build/unirest/setup.py) egg_info for package unirest

    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'docs'
Downloading/unpacking poster>=0.8.1 (from unirest)
  Downloading poster-0.8.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/home/nick/.virtualenvs/mashape/build/poster/setup.py) egg_info for package poster
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/home/nick/.virtualenvs/mashape/build/poster/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
        import poster
      File "/home/nick/.virtualenvs/mashape/build/poster/poster/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
        import poster.streaminghttp
      File "/home/nick/.virtualenvs/mashape/build/poster/poster/streaminghttp.py", line 61
        print "send:", repr(value)
                    ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/home/nick/.virtualenvs/mashape/build/poster/setup.py", line 2, in <module>

    import poster

  File "/home/nick/.virtualenvs/mashape/build/poster/poster/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>

    import poster.streaminghttp

  File "/home/nick/.virtualenvs/mashape/build/poster/poster/streaminghttp.py", line 61

    print "send:", repr(value)

                ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/nick/.virtualenvs/mashape/build/poster
Storing debug log for failure in /home/nick/.pip/pip.log
```

For now I am using 2.7 but I prefer to use 3.x for new projects.

Comment: I think you should use pip3, which is the python 3's version of pip.

Comment: @Krishath used pip3, same error

Comment: If the project uses `print` it probably is not Python 3 compatible, no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The project is not Python 3 compatible. When the project doesn't explicitly state this (not in the `setup.py` trove classifiers nor in documentation), you'll have to look at the [source code](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-python/).

There I find:

- [no `use_2to3` use in setup](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-python/blob/master/setup.py) to automatically rewrite code on install
- [imports for `urllib2`](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-python/blob/master/unirest/__init__.py#L53), a Python 2 only library.

The project depends on the [`poster` library](http://atlee.ca/software/poster/), which is also [`urllib2` specific](https://bitbucket.org/chrisatlee/poster/src/97d3c6fcb87785d1838549301f0092dec4229abf/poster/streaminghttp.py?at=default#cl-29).

I'd use the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) instead. It supports Python 3 out of the box, and apart from asynchronous requests it supports the same feature set (but better as it doesn't have the shortcomings `urllib2` brings along). For asynchronous requests, you can add on [`requests-futures`](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures).

Comment: Thanks. It is a bit crazy to me that mashape releases a relatively new library and it is python2 only. I think I'm just going to use the requests library and skip this.

Comment: Most of the features purported by that library are also available in the [`requests` project](http://python-requests.org); the async part is implemented with a thread, `requests` has [better options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests) for async work. `requests` works great on Python 3.