# Does python-requests have any callback method?

Tags: python, python-requests, gevent

Here is what I am looking for.

```
s = Session()    

s.get(url, callback=self.do_this)

def do_this(self, response):
    print response.url
```

Comment: Why not foo = request. get() do_this(foo). Requests is synchronous, so callbacks don't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests ?

Comment: I think asynchronous requests are better than synchronous requests. No? @NickBailey

Comment: @JonClements, yes.I forgot to mention that I want to use callback with Session. Is it possible?

Comment: Because you might read the documentation, not see the word "callbacks" and not realize that "event hooks" was the right term?

Answer (score 6):

You can use event hooks:

```py
def display_url(r, **kwargs):
    print(r.url)


s = Session()
s.hooks['response'].append(display_url)

s.get(...)
```

Documentation here: https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/advanced/#event-hooks

Answer (score 2):

Use [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) to have asynchronous requests with gevent. There is a `callback` keyword argument to `.get()`.

Comment: there is no `callback` keyword to `.get()`

Comment: @EliavLouski `get` is an `AsyncRequest` , it takes a `callback` keyword argument - so you can do `from grequests import get ; get(url, callback=func)` it is even written in the `AsyncRequest` docstring... This is still valid in latest 0.6.0