# How to pass arguments to a callback function in Python?

Tags: python, function, http, callback

I want to make my code Async for HTTP calls, since the whole program stops while the call is being made.

I took a look at grequests and couldn't figure it out, same for asyncio

this is the current sync version of the code:

```
myvar1 = class_object()

response = requests.get(myvar1.url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    myvar1.accept()
```

I would like to do the following instead:

```
def myfunction:

    request.get(myvar1.url,callbackfunction(response,myvar1))

    return None

def callbackfunction(response,myvar1):

    if response.status_code == 200:
        myvar1.accept()
```

I can successfully pass a callback function to the request, the question is how to pass arguments to that callback.

Basically, the goal is to execute a method of the passed argument of the callback function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does python-requests have any callback method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095006/does-python-requests-have-any-callback-method)

Comment: I can successfully pass a callback function to the request, the question is how to pass arguments to that callback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, how to pass an argument to a function pointer parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783211/python-how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-function-pointer-parameter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets make a partial function:

```
def myfunction(var, func):

    request.get(var.url, callback =  func)


def callbackfunction(response, var):

    if response.status_code == 200:
        var.accept()

# Now make a partial function to wrap callbackfunction
def wrapper(var):
    def callback(response):
        callbackfunction(response, var)
    return callback

myvar1 = class_object()

myfunction(myvar1, wrapper(myvar1))
```

So, `requests.get()` will eventually call `func(response)` which in fact will be `callback(response)` which calls `callbackfunction(response, myvar1)`