# calling functions via grequests

Tags: python, asynchronous, request, grequests

I realize there have been many posts on grequests such as [Asynchronous Requests with Python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests)
which describes the basic usage of grequests and how to send hooks via `grequests.get()` I pulled this bit of code right from that link.

```
import grequests

urls = [
    'http://python-requests.org',
    'http://httpbin.org',
    'http://python-guide.org',
    'http://kennethreitz.com'
]

# A simple task to do to each response object
def do_something(response):
    print ('print_test')

# A list to hold our things to do via async
async_list = []

for u in urls:
    action_item = grequests.get(u, hooks = {'response' : do_something})

    async_list.append(action_item)

# Do our list of things to do via async
grequests.map(async_list)
```

When i run this however i get no output

```
/$ python test.py
/$
```

since there are 4 links I would expect the output to be

```
print_test
print_test
print_test
print_test
```

I have been searching around and haven't been able to find a reason for the lack of output I am amusing that there is a bit of key information that I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to check sources yet, but if you rewrite your hook function as

```
# A simple task to do to each response object
def do_something(response, *args, **kwargs):
    print ('print_test')
```

it puts output. So it's probably failing to call you original hook(because it passes more arguments than you accept) and catching exception, so you get no output

Comment: Awesome thanks for the response just tried it out and it works perfect!  I believe you are correct about the amount of arguments.

Comment: printed kwargs. Turned out library passes whole bunch of key-word arguments to your hook function. `{'proxies': OrderedDict(), 'timeout': None, 'stream': False, 'cert': None, 'verify': True}`