# Whats the fastest way to get movie info from omdb with python?

Tags: python, json, api, csv, movie

I have about 200 thousand `imdb_id` in a file, and want to get `JSON` information from these `imdb_id` using `omdb` API.

I wrote this code and it works correctly, but it's very slow (3 Seconds for each id, it would take 166 Hours):

```
import urllib.request
import csv
import datetime
from collections import defaultdict


i = 0
columns = defaultdict(list)
with open('a.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for (k, v) in row.items():
            columns[k].append(v)
with open('a.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvinput:
    with open('b.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
        for row in csv.reader(csvinput):
            if row[0] == "item_id":
                writer.writerow(row + ["movie_info"])
            else:
                url = urllib.request.urlopen(
                    "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt" + str(columns['item_id'][i]) + "&apikey=??????").read()
                url = url.decode('utf-8')
                writer.writerow((row + [url]))
                i = i + 1
```

Whats the fastest way to get movie info from omdb with python ???

**Edited : I wrote this code and after get 1022 url resopnse i hava this error :

```
import grequests

urls = open("a.csv").readlines()
api_key = '??????'


def exception_handler(request, exception):
    print("Request failed")


# read file and put each lines to an LIST
for i in range(len(urls)):
    urls[i] = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt" + str(urls[i]).rstrip('\n') + "&apikey=" + api_key
requests = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
responses = grequests.map(requests, exception_handler=exception_handler)
with open('b.json', 'wb') as outfile:
    for response in responses:
        outfile.write(response.content)
```

Error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/python_apps/omdb_async.py", line 18, in <module>
    outfile.write(response.content)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content'
```

How can i solve this error ???

Answer (score 2):

This code is IO bound and would benefit greatly from using Python's async/await capabilities.  You can loop over your collection of URLs, creating an asynchronously executing request for each, much like the example in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests).

Once you're making these requests asynchronously, you may need to throttle your request rate to something within the OMDB API limit.