# How to execute requests.get without attachment Python

Tags: python, python-requests

Right now I am trying to execute asynchronous requests without any related tie-in to each other, similar to how FTP can upload / download more than one file at once.

I am using the following code:

```
rec = reuests.get("https://url", stream=True)
```

With

```
rec.raw.read()
```

To get responses.

But I am wishing to be able to execute this same piece of code much faster with no need to wait for the server to respond, which takes about 2 seconds each time.

Comment: Using threads would probably be easiest.

Comment: Just used it @Shadow, already cut down to 10x quicker so far. If you post answer will uptick it.

Comment: you could try [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous Requests with Python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do something like that is to use threads.

Here is a rough example of one of the ways you might do this.

```
import requests
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool  # the exact import depends on your python version

pool = Pool(4)  # the number represents how many jobs you want to run in parallel.

def get_url(url):
    rec = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    return rec.raw.read()

for result in pool.map(get_url, ["http://url/1", "http://url/2"]:
    do_things(result)
```

Comment: Wouldn’t using the grequests module be an easier way to do asynchronous get requests? From my experience, it has been much faster.

Comment: As mentioned - this is only one of the ways you could do it. There are plenty of others, `threading` module included.