# Python, fire and forget POST to service

Tags: python, asynchronous, post

I have a service running locally that fires content to a FireBase database. If there is no connection it stores it locally in a JSON file and works through it when there is a connection.

I want to fire content to this service from my main script but not wait for a response. How can I fire the following event without waiting for a response?

```
  r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8002/", params={'Bib': row[0][2], 'Name': row[0][0] + " " + row[0][1], 'phoneNumber':+ row[0][3], 'sTime': row[0][5],  'Time':row[0][4]})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous Requests with Python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests)