# Using a task queue in django without leaking kwargs

Tags: django, task, celery, django-celery, task-queue

I want to create a webpage using django which, when requested, presents a form asking for all kinds of user input including the user password. When submitted, a concurrent task should be started, which takes the user input as arguments and does all kinds of calculations.

Note that

1. the *task has to be started concurrently*, since the calculations can take a while and I want to inform the user immediately that his task has been accepted - I want to keep him up to date about his task in another view.
2. *the plaintext user password is part of the task arguments*. It has to be, since the calculations involve encryption operations which rely on the password.

Now I would just use celery and django_celery_results as result backend for this goal (and already started using it), when I noticed: Whoa... django_celery_results stores the plaintext password as part of the task kwargs in the database. That's not cool.
Also the whole RabbitMQ messaging of the plaintext password seems a bit unsecure to me, after reading the [celery security documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/security.html). And who knows in which logs celery writes the passwords.

To sum it up: celery and other task qeues not seem to be designed to handle sensible informations as arguments. I really just need to start a simple concurrent task, update its status and store its result in the database. I want to stay purely in python3 and django. Any recommendations?

**Edit:**

- I do not want to use javascript for this. I want to use serverside form validation and start the asynchronous task there.
- Applying reduction functions, hash functions or any other transformations to the user password does not solve the problem. Whatever I supply my task queue with, needs to be sufficient to perform the encryption/decryption operations and is therefore highly sensible.
- I search for a solution where the plaintext password is only stored in memory

Comment: I would usually just use some small js ajax request script in my views, but you could try looking at this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#ajax-example, or simulating an ajax request like in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests

Comment: Don't use the plain text password - apply a reduction function to the encoded password to produce a plain text string

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of solution would work for you. You need to store the parameters somewhere, surely