# Send multiple get requests for the same url using python

Tags: python, asynchronous, https, request

I have to send a couple of thousand get requests for the same url.
It's quite long when I do that by using for loop, so I looking a better/faster/ ̶s̶t̶r̶o̶n̶g̶e̶r̶- solution.
Do you have any ideas?

```
url = 'https://site.ru:port/api/v2/getRequest'

for index, row in tqdm.tqdm(data.iterrows(), total=data.shape[0]):

        params = {

            'param1_key' : row['param1_value'],
            'param2_key' : row['param2_value'}

        response = requests.get(api_endpoint, params, headers={'apikey': api_key}, timeout=30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do it in a for loop, you have to wait for a response each time. So to make it <s>better/</s>faster<s>/stronger</s>... 
Do it async with [`requests-futures`](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures) or [`grequests`](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests)!

(Also see  [Asynchronous Requests with Python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests) - it's pretty dated though and points you to grequests anyway)

Comment: @Fabor, thanks so much, grequest works, but I'm confused cause can't find how to pass api key there (grequest.get). Do you know?

Comment: @G_V grequests sends all kwargs to requests, so you should be able to do it the same way. `grequests.get("http://localhost:8075", params={"p1": 5}, headers={'apikey': "my_key"}).send()` has worked for me. It results in this HTTP request: `GET /?p1=5 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8075
User-Agent: python-requests/2.23.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
apikey: my_key`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without more info. `iterrows` if knows not to be fast, but I would bet a coin that the most time consuming part is waiting for the response from the server.

In that case `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` can be a handy tool to start multiple concurrent requests without waiting for each to terminate before starting the next one. But beware, sending too many requests to a single server can be seen as an attack...