# The waitForResponse method doesn't work with XMLHTTP

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest

I have a code in which I declared a variable like that

```
Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
```

then in the code, I used this line

```
http.Open "POST", urlexample, False
http.Send strArg
```

How can I use the `waitForResponse` to wait for the server to respond to the request. I tried looping like that after the `.Send` statement

```
While http.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

But this works sometimes well and sometimes doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through object model seems that this method is not available through `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` but is with `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest`. The latter does not have a `ReadyState` property however.

[image]

You'll need to investigate the default timeout and see if you need SetTimeOuts on WinHttp object to obtain longer times.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub testing()
    Dim http As winHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Set http = New winHttp.WinHttpRequest
  
    With http
        '.SetTimeouts ........
        .Open "GET", "http://books.toscrape.com/", True
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        .waitForResponse 1000
    End With
    Stop
End Sub
```

N.B. Your request will not be async if the async arg is set to FALSE in the `.Open`

---

Interesting reading: `https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web/issues/337`

Seems Tim Hall's VBA-Web would be a nice pre-packaged way to go about this.

[WinHTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/about-winhttp)

Comment: I'm at work. If this is a new question please open one as others may be able to answer it before I get to look at it.

Comment: I have a weird case, sometimes the response has only one table while when navigating to the website, I found two tables. So it seems I have to wait till it is loaded properly (I am not sure). i tried to increate the timeout to 3000 but the same problem happens sometimes too. To your information, the problem is not happening all the time. But it is occassionally occur. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you set async to True? I am not saying that is the solution. I am asking how you are currently running please?

Comment: I am using False in the code. I will try using the True to see if this will make difference or not.

Comment: I expect True to make situation worse! Have a look at @Omegastripes async answers for VBA. I think he answered one of your questions before.

Comment: When I used the True I got an error at the part of `.waitForResponse`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228890/discussion-between-qharr-and-yasserkhalil).

Comment: Thanks a lot. What's the equivalent in python for that wait in requests package?

Comment: @YasserKhalil Equivalent of? There are [timeouts](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts) but requests is not async. Async was moved: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests

Comment: I don't think async is the right case for me. The problem with me with specific webpage which has one or two tables (sometimes one table and sometimes two tables). The problem happens with me when only one table is loaded and when manually go to that web page I found two tables .. That's too weird, and this webpage is loaded by javascript commands. So what I am seeking for is something that guarantee the full-load of the webpage ..

Comment: What's the webpage? Are you sure one table isn't loaded by javascript?

Comment: I have explained the details on that link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66295832/webpage-not-loaded-fully-all-the-time-in-python-requests

Comment: ok.. but how do I get direct to the problem url without reading all the code please?

Comment: I don't know as the page is related to entering the case number and the captcha then go to the specific page. I have put the HTML for that page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229001/discussion-between-qharr-and-yasserkhalil).