# Python - Append to Docitionary List

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary with a list that appears like this:

```
{'subscription_id_list': ['92878351', '93153640', '93840845', '93840847'.......]
```

There will be up to 10,000 entries in the list for each call to the API.  What I want to do is loop and append the list so when complete, my {'subscription_id_list'} contains everything.

Any thoughts?

Comment: A few more details: you're making calls to an API based on the contents of a list? Or you're making calls to an API and want a list to contain the responses?  What does your `{'subscription_id_list'}` contain at the start, and from what do the results come to add to it?

Comment: From my limited understanding, is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests) relevant to what you want?

Comment: The result from the call is just like that:  {'subscription_id_list': ['92878351', '93153640', '93840845', '93840847'.......]}      So, after making X number of calls, each one returning this same structure, in the end I'd like a single dictionary list with all the elements.  So, {'subscription_id_list': ['92878351', '93153640', '93840845', '93840847', '12345','123455','666','888','999','000','443242',..............}  And so on, might be 100,000 entries in the list after everything is appended.    Just not sure how to do the appending.

Comment: How's that? you make multiple calls, each returning you a list? And you want to combine all those lists? Could you provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (abstracting away the not-relevant stuff as you see fit)?

Comment: Possibly also relevant if you haven't already considered it: [asynchronous http requests in python](https://www.twilio.com/blog/asynchronous-http-requests-in-python-with-aiohttp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have something like

```py
for api_request in some_structure:
    response = get_remote_results(api_request)
    # response structure is single-key dict,
    # key is 'subscription_id_list'; value is list of str of int
    # i.e. {'subscription-id-list': ['1234','5678',....]}
```

and you want some complete `dict` to contain the `list` of all values in the various responses. Then use [`list.extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```py
complete_sub_id_list = []
for api_request in some_structure:
    response = get_remote_results(api_request)
    complete_sub_id_list.extend(response['subscription_id_list'])
```

As noted in a comment, if you're making API requests to a remote server or resource (or even something dependent on local I/O), you're likely going to want to use asynchronous calls; if you're not already familiar with what that means, perhaps [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) and/or [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) will be quite helpful. See e.g. [this Twilio guide](https://www.twilio.com/blog/asynchronous-http-requests-in-python-with-aiohttp) for more info.  **TL;DR** you could see 5-30x speedup as opposed to using synchronous calls.

Comment: Pretty much.   And after all the calls, I'd like to have a single key dictionary with all the elements.   Probably have to assign it to a new variable, but not sure how to do the appending........

Comment: Ok, very simple.   Many many thanks!!