# Fastest way to make 800+ get requests using same url but passing different ids everytime

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, http

What would be the fastest way to load Device IDs from an excel sheet which contains 800+ Device IDs and pass these Device IDs in a http get request.

I'm fetching Device IDs from the excel sheet, making http get request to get the relevant data and dump it into a list and then save it in an excel file using : -

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    excel_file = openpyxl.load_workbook("D:\mypath\Book1.xlsx")
    active_sheet = excel_file.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet4")

    def iter_rows(active_sheet):
        for row in active_sheet.iter_rows(): 
            yield [cell.value for cell in row]

    res = iter_rows(active_sheet)
    keys = next(res)

    final_data_to_dump = []
    failed_data_dump = []

    for new in res:
        
        inventory_data = dict(zip(keys, new))
        if None in inventory_data.values():
            pass
        else:
            
            url_get_event = 'https://some_url&source={}'.format(inventory_data['DeviceID'])

            header_events = {
            'Authorization': 'Basic authkey_here'}

            print(inventory_data['DeviceID'])
            try:
                r3 = requests.get(url_get_event, headers=header_events)
                r3_json = json.loads(r3.content)
                if r3_json['events']:
                    for object in r3_json['events']:

                        dict_excel_data = {

                            "DeviceID":object['source']['id'],
                            "Device Name":object['source']['name'],
                            "Start 1":object['Start1'],
                            "Start 2":object['Start2'],
                            "Watering Mode":object['WateringMode'],
                            "Duration":object['ActuationDetails']['Duration'],
                            "Type":object['type'],
                            "Creation Time":object['creationTime']
                        }

                        final_data_to_dump.append(dict_excel_data)
                else:
                    no_dict_excel_data = {

                            "DeviceID":inventory_data["DeviceID"],
                            "Device Name":inventory_data["DeviceName"],
                            "Start 1":"",
                            "Start 2":"",
                            "Watering Mode":"",
                            "Duration":"",
                            "Type":"",
                            "Creation Time":""
                        }

                    final_data_to_dump.append(no_dict_excel_data)

            except requests.ConnectionError:
                failed_dict_excel_data = {

                        "DeviceID":inventory_data['DeviceID'],
                        "Device Name":inventory_data["DeviceName"],
                        "Status":"Connection Error"
                    }

                failed_data_dump.append(failed_dict_excel_data)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(final_data_to_dump)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(failed_data_dump)
    df.to_excel('D:\mypath\ReportReceived_10Apr.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False)     
    df2.to_excel('D:\mypath\Failed_ReportReceived_10Apr.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False)
```

But this can take upwards of 10-15 mins as there are 800+ devices in the Book1 sheet and it's likely to increase. How can I make this process faster?

Comment: You are using 800+ sequential requests. each other one is done when the earlier one is finished. You need to parrallelize or use async etc.

Comment: Read [asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests) - it may answer your question.

Comment: You can use async tasks or threads to run multiple requests at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an async library, but the easiest solution here would be to do something like

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as exc:
    responses = exc.map(get, device_ids)

def get(device_id):
    url_get_event = 'https://some_url&source={}'.format(device_id)
    return requests.get(url_get_event)
```

---

If the other part of your code is small you may want to submit the functions to the executor and use `as_completed` to handle them in the main thread while waiting for other requests to run too.