# Trying to get 2 values returned from async aiohttp get call

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Today I was trying to speed up my script and found great example code from another stackoverflow post. Basically I found a way to make async requests using aiohttp to web instead of using requests. Here is the link to that post (I copied code from DragonBobZ's answer).

[Link to other stackoverflow post from which I copied code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests)

The issue is that I am trying to get it to return 2 values (url, response) instead of just the response from the request made. Here is the code I took.

```
def async_aiohttp_get_all(urls, cookies):
    async def get_all(urls):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(cookies=cookies) as session:
            async def fetch(url):
                async with session.get(url) as response:
                    return await response.json()
            return await asyncio.gather(*[
                fetch(url) for url in urls
            ])

    return sync.async_to_sync(get_all)(urls)

for x in async_aiohttp_get_all(urls_list, s.cookies.get_dict()):
    print(x)
```

Now I am successfully able to get responses from all urls within fraction of time it was taking with requests but I want the function to also return the url with:

```
return await response.json()
```

I tried this but nothing works and this is my first day to ever use async practices in python so I am not even able to search for a solution as nothing makes sense.

```
return await url, response.json()
return await (url, response.json())
```

Comment: So it turns out the error was just because I was trying to await url which of course was wrong. When I changed to return await response.json(), url from return await url, response.json(), then it all worked correctly. Now I get it that function needs to wait for response since url is just a static variable already present.

Comment: However, I accepted the answer as it solves my issue and that too without using sync (asgiref) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not run the code exactly how you do, but I returned a tuple with no problem. Also removed the `sync` call, since `asyncio` gives you enough flexibility.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

urls_list = [
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.facebook.com",
    "https://www.twitter.com",
]

async def async_aiohttp_get_all(urls, cookies):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(cookies=cookies) as session:
        async def fetch(url):
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                return await response.text(), url
        return await asyncio.gather(*[
            fetch(url) for url in urls
        ])

results = asyncio.run(async_aiohttp_get_all(urls_list, None))
for res in results:
    print(res[0][:10], res[1])
```

Output:

```
<!doctype  https://www.google.com
<!DOCTYPE  https://www.facebook.com
<!DOCTYPE  https://www.twitter.com
```

So, in your case, `return await response.json(), url` should work.

Comment: Thank you. Your code suggestion works exactly as expected. Now sure why the code in question did not work for me. I kept getting this error when I tried to return both response and url.

TypeError: object tuple can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: That error ocurrs if you call `await (response.json(), url)`. `( )` in python is a constructor for tuple type too and await expects a coroutine not a tuple, a coroutine is obtained invoking an async def like in this case `response.json()`.