# Pandas - Parallelize the pinging of a list of websites

Tags: pandas, parallel-processing, apply, ping, urllib3

I have a list of 100 websites that I want to ping to see if they are live or not. I want to record the status returned for each record in a new field called 'status'. I have stored them in a dataframe and was hoping to use the apply function to parallelize the exercise, taking advantage of up to 8 cores on my laptop. At the moment it takes about 3m 30s, and i was naively hoping to get that down to less than 30 seconds. I've tried swifter but without success. I'd prefer some sort of apply function but am open to using multiprocessing / multithreading modules. I am not a programmer so this is really the limit of my abilities at the moment.
Appreciate any ideas / advice

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import urllib3
import swifter

#Load data to dataframe
#List of sites
siteList=[['1','https://www.facebook.com'],[2,'https://www.instagram.com'], [3,'https://www.mail.com'],[4,'https://www.thegrumpyscarecrow.com/']]

df = pd.DataFrame(siteList, columns=['id','site'])

#functions
def getStatusCode(url):
    try:
        r = requests.head(url, verify=False, timeout=5)
        return (r.status_code)
    except:
        return -1

#Run the script
df['status'] = df.swifter.allow_dask_on_strings(enable=True).apply(lambda x: getStatusCode(x['site']), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Comment: Parallelism is not what you need here. You need *concurrency*. Using more cores does not make network request faster (but it introduces new issues related to parallelism). Latency hiding is what is mainly needed to reduce the runtime. Asynchronous operations are made for that. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests

Comment: Thanks for explaining this much better than I did @JérômeRichard ! Having read up concurrency makes much more sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `swifter`, you can use [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
requests.urllib3.disable_warnings()

def getStatusCode(url):
    try:
        r = requests.head(url, verify=False, timeout=5)
        status = r.status_code
    except ConnectionError:
        status = -1
    return status

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    status = executor.map(getStatusCode, df['site'])
df['status'] = list(status)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   id                                 site  status
0   1             https://www.facebook.com     200
1   2            https://www.instagram.com     200
2   3                 https://www.mail.com     200
3   4  https://www.thegrumpyscarecrow.com/      -1
```

Comment: Thanks @corralien ! This worked perfectly, and gave me up to an 80% improvement in execution time! Really great and simple to understand code as well!