# Python concurrent request issue

Tags: python, concurrency

I have an email list (100000 emails), I want to iterate through the list and call multiple http requests to send emails in parallel using emails in the list, and maximum number of sending email requests is 50.

Here's the code:

```
...
first50emails = allEmails[0:49]

def sendEmail(email):
    ...
    requests.post(sendMailAPI, data=data)
    # call send Email API again if something goes wrong with the API
    if res.status_code != 200:
        sendEmail(email)
        return
    # when finish sending an email, call concurrentExecute with new email
    nextEmail = [getNextEmail()]
    concurrentExecute(nextEmail)

def concurrentExecute(emailList):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = {executor.submit(sendEmail, email): email for email in emailList}

concurrentExecute(first50emails)
```

At first, I get first 50 emails in the list and let it run in parallel using concurrentExecute function. And whenever an email is sent (inside function sendEmail), I'll get one more email from the allEmails list and call concurrentExecute function with the new email.

If there's any errors with the send email API, I just call sendEmail request again.

The problem is that after sending few hundreds of emails, the program just exits without any error. I tried couple of times and same results

Comment: _the program just stop_ What do you mean by "stop"?  Do you mean it **exits**, or do you mean it **freezes**?

Comment: You are recursively calling sendEmail.  I suggest you put the post method in a loop checking the status code and iterating if not 200 or some max times to retry.

Comment: there is a hard maximum recursion depth for method calls.  FYI.

Comment: @JohnGordon it just exits

Comment: @LhasaDad what do you suggest, do you know what would cause this?

Comment: If you need to send HTTP requests to many URLs at once, I suggest using the code shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests

Comment: If you're sending 100000 emails through your own server you will need to be very careful that you don't get blacklisted. You would do well to consider services like Sendgrid who will handle the mailing problem and also deal with any blacklisting issues.

Comment: I have no idea at the moment what would cause it though I think the blacklisting comment has merit.  You might output the status codes you are seeing to see what response you are getting on the request.  just plowing ahead might get you no results.