# What is the difference between multiprocessing and subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing

My work should use parallel techniques, and I am new user of Python. I wonder if you could share some material about the Python `multiprocessing` and `subprocess` modules. What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Potentially also look at `greenlets` - but avoid those until you've understood the answers given to your OP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deciding among subprocess, multiprocessing, and thread in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629680/deciding-among-subprocess-multiprocessing-and-thread-in-python)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The `subprocess` module lets you run and control other programs. Anything you can start with the command line on the computer, can be run and controlled with this module. Use this to integrate external programs into your Python code.

The `multiprocessing` module lets you divide tasks written in python over multiple processes to help improve performance. It provides an API very similar to the `threading` module; it provides methods to share data across the processes it creates, and makes the task of managing multiple processes to run Python code (much) easier. In other words, `multiprocessing` lets you take advantage of multiple processes to get your tasks done faster by executing code in parallel.

Comment: @glglgl: I am sorry I caused you pain. Thanks for cleaning that up. :-) Lets see if I can keep my apostrophes in check!

Comment: "*The subprocess module lets you run and control other programs.*", sure, but does it use a thread or a process to run them? That's the interesting detail. Seems it uses a thread to create a new process asynchronously, and the thread continues to communicate with the process.

Comment: @mins: the new process is run as a fork of the current process, which is then replaced by the child process via an `execv` or `execve` system call. No threads are involved nor would they help in creating the new process any faster. Communication is mostly handled by pipes (so, the OS). If you want to use threads, you can, or you could use asyncio. Your choice.

Comment: Thanks, I guess fork/exec is equivalent to Windows [spawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spawn_(computing)).

Answer (score 51):

If you want to call an external program (especially one not written in Python) use `subprocess`.

If you want to call a Python function in a subprocess, use `multiprocessing`.

(If the program is written in Python, but is also importable, then I would try to call its functions using `multiprocessing`, rather than calling it externally through `subprocess`.)

Comment: What if it is an external program and I want to run it on multiple processors?

Comment: Do you want to run the external program multiple times, or do you want to run the external program as a single process in such a way as to take advantage of multiple processors?

Comment: Multiple times, parallely. To be precise, OCRing multiple image files.

Comment: You can launch multiple [non-blocking `subprocess.call`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16071866/190597). Any modern OS should run the processes concurrently over the available processors. You could also launch the [subprocesses from a thread pool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26783779/190597) to limit the number of subprocesses launched concurrently.

Comment: Can you please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53838992/multiple-subprocesses-take-a-lot-of-time-to-complete)?

Answer (score 23):

Subprocess spawns new processes, but aside from stdin/stdout and whatever other APIs the other program may implement you have no means to communicate with them.  Its main purpose is to launch processes that are completely separate from your own program.

Multiprocessing also spawns new processes, but they run your code, and are designed to communicate with each other.  You use it to divide tasks within your own program across multiple CPU cores.

Comment: "*Subprocess spawns new processes [...] Multiprocessing also spawns new processes, but they run your code*", what prevents the subprocess module to launch a process running your code? "*and are designed to communicate with each other*", if processes can communicate, what prevents the ones spawned by the subprocess module to communicate too?

Comment: @mins: Processes spawned via `subprocess` can't (easily if at all) take advantage of the ways process can communicate that are started using `multiprocessing.Process`, such as via a [`multiprocessing.Manager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers).