# Non blocking subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to make a non blocking subprocess call to run a slave.py script from my main.py program. I need to pass args from main.py to slave.py once when it(slave.py) is first started via subprocess.call after this slave.py runs for a period of time then exits.

```
main.py
for insert, (list) in enumerate(list, start =1):

    sys.args = [list]
    subprocess.call(["python", "slave.py", sys.args], shell = True)


{loop through program and do more stuff..}
```

And my slave script

```
slave.py
print sys.args
while True:
    {do stuff with args in loop till finished}
    time.sleep(30)
```

Currently, slave.py blocks main.py from running the rest of its tasks, I simply want slave.py to be independent of main.py, once I've passed args to it. The two scripts no longer need to communicate.

I've found a few posts on the net about non blocking subprocess.call but most of them are centered on requiring communication with slave.py at some-point which I currently do not need. Would anyone know how to implement this in a simple fashion...?

Answer (score 83):

You should use `subprocess.Popen` instead of `subprocess.call`.

Something like:

```
subprocess.Popen(["python", "slave.py"] + sys.argv[1:])
```

From the [docs on `subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

> Run the command described by args. **Wait for command to complete**, then return the returncode attribute.

(Also don't use a list to pass in the arguments if you're going to use `shell = True`).

---

Here's a MCVE<sup>1</sup> example that demonstrates a non-blocking suprocess call:

```
import subprocess
import time

p = subprocess.Popen(['sleep', '5'])

while p.poll() is None:
    print('Still sleeping')
    time.sleep(1)

print('Not sleeping any longer.  Exited with returncode %d' % p.returncode)
```

An alternative approach that relies on more recent changes to the python language to allow for co-routine based parallelism is:

```
# python3.5 required but could be modified to work with python3.4.
import asyncio

async def do_subprocess():
    print('Subprocess sleeping')
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec('sleep', '5')
    returncode = await proc.wait()
    print('Subprocess done sleeping.  Return code = %d' % returncode)

async def sleep_report(number):
    for i in range(number + 1):
        print('Slept for %d seconds' % i)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

tasks = [
    asyncio.ensure_future(do_subprocess()),
    asyncio.ensure_future(sleep_report(5)),
]

loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
loop.close()
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>Tested on OS-X using python2.7 & python3.6</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this appears to work, however when I include a While loop in slave.py it seems get stuck and not perform anything in the loop (even with a timer.sleep() function..?

Comment: @mgilson : Can you please share a general example on how to use it ?. I mean how the control flow should look like when using it in a non blocking way. I appreciate it.

Comment: @ViFI -- Sure, I've added an example of using `Popen` in a non-blocking way.

Comment: Is there a way to start multiple processes asynchronously like `p1 & p2 &` and then wait on all of them using `asyncio`? I'm hoping this does not require the multiprocessing module.

Comment: Sure, you'd just need a `do_p1` function and a `do_p2` function and you'd add both of them to the `tasks` list.

Comment: What's the difference between `subprocess.Popen` and the alternative approach using `asyncio`?

Answer (score 32):

There's three levels of thoroughness here.

As mgilson says, if you just swap out `subprocess.call` for `subprocess.Popen`, keeping everything else the same, then main.py will not wait for slave.py to finish before it continues.  That may be enough by itself.  If you care about [zombie processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) hanging around, you should save the object returned from `subprocess.Popen` and at some later point call its `wait` method.  (The zombies will automatically go away when main.py exits, so this is only a serious problem if main.py runs for a very long time and/or might create many subprocesses.)  And finally, if you don't want a zombie but you also don't want to decide where to do the waiting (this might be appropriate if both processes run for a long and unpredictable time afterward), use the [python-daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon) library to have the slave disassociate itself from the master -- in that case you can continue using `subprocess.call` in the master.

Answer (score 5):

For Python 3.8.x

```
import shlex
import subprocess

cmd = "<full filepath plus arguments of child process>"
cmds = shlex.split(cmd)
p = subprocess.Popen(cmds, start_new_session=True)
```

This will allow the parent process to exit while the child process continues to run. Not sure about zombies.

Tested on Python 3.8.1 on macOS 10.15.5

Comment: Shlex seems like overkill for this example.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution for your non-blocking situation would be to add  `&` at the end of the `Popen` like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(["python", "slave.py", " &"])
```

This does not block the execution of the rest of the program.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that just passes " &" as an argument to "python"

Comment: `&`, in the context of trying to background things, is a shell directive. It has no effect when (as here) you aren't actually invoking a shell; so as Zendel says, it's just putting the string `' &'` into the `sys.argv` of the child process.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a function several times with different arguments in a non-blocking way, you can use the ThreadPoolExecuter.

You submit your function calls to the executer like this

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def threadmap(fun, xs):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executer:
        return list(executer.map(fun, xs))
```