# Python audio without root privileges?

Tags: python, audio, root, libraries

I working in python on computers in a lab where I do not have root privileges and can't get any libraries installed.  Someone I am helping is writing a game and wants to add audio.  We can play sounds with something like this

subprocess.call(["afplay","gun_battle_sound-ReamProductions-1158375208.wav"])

but everything stops until the sound is done playing.  Is there a way to keep things moving while the audio is playing?  Is there a library that we can just copy?  We are using the graphics module from Zelle, so I am looking for something like that - simple to use and install.

Thank you!

Comment: Regarding your library Installation problem: What about using virtualenv to create your own local python distribution (in your home directory) where you can install all the libraries you want (well, maybe not heavy-stuff like scipy). The only thing you need: virtualenv has to be installed/available!

Comment: For what it's worth, there's [`subprocess.Popen`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071866/non-blocking-subprocess-call), but then you have to deal with zombies.

Comment: Hmm.  I tried Popen -

`>>> subprocess.Popen(["afplay","gun_battle_sound-ReamProductions-1158375208.wav"])
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x10662e110>`

But it didn't play - it just returned the object, as shown.  I'm afraid to as it to install anything, but maybe I should get over it and ask them about virtualenv.  It sounds like a nice option to have.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have success using `subprocess.Popen` executing `afplay` to play a WAV file (using the same arguments) in Python 2.7.

Comment: OK, I tried it again and it worked (?!?)  Thanks, all!

Answer (score 0):

[Pyglet](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/wiki/Home)
is completely copyable and easy to download.
Otherwise you will probably need to create a thread from threading just for the sound to play on.