# Rest of code won't execute until launched programme is closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, raspbian, psutil

I'm launching a programme with subprocess and follow that command with a for loop. The loop won't run until the programme I launched is closed. I don't understand why this is. Could someone please explain?

**My Code:**

```
import subprocess
import psutil

subprocess.call('/path_to/programme.exe')
for process in psutil.process_iter():
    print(process)
```

I'm running Raspbian OS on a Pi 3 (armv7l).

Thanks for your time.

L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subprocess.call will wait until the command completes. Use subprocess.Popen instead.

This question is a duplicate of [Non blocking subprocess.call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071866/non-blocking-subprocess-call)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know what I was looking for exactly so I must have missed that. Will I delete this post?

Comment: That’s okay. I’ll flag it as a duplicate and it should get closed.