# Run Flask app inside of another flask app

Tags: python, linux, flask, subprocess

I am using Flask to build kind of a launcher for other Flask Apps. So the user would start the python flask server on their local machine and then they could start other flask apps they might have. The problem is, when I try to run other flask apps while the original Flask app is running, it waits till it is done but I want it to run both.

For example, I might have

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    if(request.form['launch'] = "Launch"):
      subprocess.call(['. ../Apps/appname/run'])
```

where 'run' is a bash/shell script I wrote that has python3 app.py in the correct directory but it will not work unless I end the flask first flask app

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071866/non-blocking-subprocess-call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non blocking subprocess.call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071866/non-blocking-subprocess-call)