# Python subprocess Popen in async manner

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, subprocess

Consider you want to launch in a loop several parallel processes in async way, and of course, get for each process its exit code and prints.

If we do something naive like:

```py
i = 5
While i > 0:
    p = sp.Popen(["./my_module.py", "arg1", "arg2"], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    result = p.returncode
    i -= 1
```

This probably not work async because of `communicate` blocking method above.
Any ideas for the best simple way to achieve multiple processes allocation async way, and finally getting their results accumulated in list or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non blocking subprocess.call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071866/non-blocking-subprocess-call)

Comment: @ThiagoBarcala: I havn't seen any concrete solution to accumulate results of several processes runs, in addition I prefer to avoid asyncio

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://github.com/omnilib/aiomultiprocess) project. It is an asynchronous multiprocessing implementation.

**UPDATE**:
Also `subprocess` module from stdlib now supports `asyncio`, check the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html