# subprocess.wait(timeout=15) is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, exe

Code:

```
import os
import subprocess


execs = ['C:\\Users\\XYZ\\PycharmProjects\\Task1\\dist\\Multiof2.exe', # --> Child 1
         'C:\\Users\\XYZ\\PycharmProjects\\Task1\\dist\\Multiof5.exe', # --> Child 2
         'C:\\Users\\XYZ\\PycharmProjects\\Task1\\dist\\Multiof10.exe',...] # --> Child 3 and more
print('Parent Process id : ', os.getpid())
process = [subprocess.Popen(exe) for exe in execs]
for proc in process:
    try:
        proc.wait(timeout=15)
        print('Child Process id : ', proc.pid)
        if proc.returncode == 0:
            print(proc.pid, 'Exited')

    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        proc.terminate()
        print('Child Process with pid',proc.pid ,'is killed')
```

Some Child Processes will take more than 15 sec to execute. So, I have to kill the process which timeout. But `proc.wait(timeout=15)` is not raising an exception instead it executes the process.

I also tried `[subprocess.Popen(exe, timeout=15) for exe in execs]` but got
Error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not waiting for the processes in parallel - you're giving them each a sequential 15 seconds to do their thing.

You might want something like this to give all of them up to 15 seconds in parallel.

```
import os
import subprocess
import time


execs = [
    "C:\\Users\\XYZ\\PycharmProjects\\Task1\\dist\\Multiof2.exe",
    "C:\\Users\\XYZ\\PycharmProjects\\Task1\\dist\\Multiof5.exe",
    "C:\\Users\\XYZ\\PycharmProjects\\Task1\\dist\\Multiof10.exe",
]
print("Parent Process id : ", os.getpid())
process = [subprocess.Popen(exe) for exe in execs]
start_time = time.time()
while True:
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    any_alive = False
    for proc in process:
        ret = proc.poll()
        if ret is None:  # still alive
            if elapsed_time >= 15:
                print("Killing:", proc.pid)
                proc.terminate()
            any_alive = True
    if not any_alive:
        break
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66247966/how-to-restart-failed-process-with-parent-process-in-python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66247966/how-to-restart-failed-process-with-parent-process-in-python Pls help me to solve.