# How to restart failed process with parent process in python

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, exe

Code:

```
execs = ['C:\\Users\\XYZ\\PycharmProjects\\Task1\\dist\\multiof1.exe',
     'C:\\Users\\XYZ\\PycharmProjects\\Task2\\dist\\multiof2.exe',
     'C:\\Users\\XYZ\\PycharmProjects\\Task3\\dist\\multiof3.exe',
     'C:\\Users\\XYZ\\PycharmProjects\\failedprocess\\dist\\multiof4.exe'
     ]

print('Parent Process id : ', os.getpid())
process = [subprocess.Popen(exe) for exe in execs]
for proc in process:
    proc.wait()
    print('Child Process id : ', proc.pid)
    if proc.poll() is not None:
        if proc.returncode == 0:
            print(proc.pid, 'Exited')
        elif proc.returncode > 0:
            print('Failed:', proc.pid)
```

In the above, .exe's one-child .exe will fail and I need to restart that failed .exe from the parent process.

I know, the above code is not a correct implementation but I googled not found a suitable solution.

Any support will help me to learn more about the subprocess.

Comment: I'd write a wrapper class for each process that takes care of polling the status and restarting a new `subprocess.Popen()` if it fails.

Comment: @AKX with Code if possible?

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service, you should be able to write a class like that yourself. In general, "with code if possible" would mean a consulting gig, but since this only took 3 minutes...

Comment: @AKX I am new to this tech and trying hard to learn about this. I googled but not found a proper or suitable sol, that suit's my requirement. so i am posting in SO for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I meant something like this with my comment:

```
import subprocess
import time

execs = [
    "C:\\Users\\XYZ\\PycharmProjects\\Task1\\dist\\multiof1.exe",
    "C:\\Users\\XYZ\\PycharmProjects\\Task2\\dist\\multiof2.exe",
    "C:\\Users\\XYZ\\PycharmProjects\\Task3\\dist\\multiof3.exe",
    "C:\\Users\\XYZ\\PycharmProjects\\failedprocess\\dist\\multiof4.exe",
]


class WrappedProcess:
    def __init__(self, exe):
        self.exe = exe
        self.process = None
        self.success = False

    def check(self):
        if self.success:  # Nothing to do, we're already successful.
            return
        if self.process is None:  # No current process, start one.
            print("Starting", self.exe)
            self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.exe)
            return  # Only poll on next check

        if self.process.poll() is None:  # Not quit yet.
            return
        if self.process.returncode == 0:
            print("Finished successfully:", self.exe)
            self.success = True
        else:
            print("Failed:", self.exe)
            # Abandon the process; next check() will retry.
            self.process = None


wrapped_processes = [WrappedProcess(exe) for exe in execs]

while True:
    for proc in wrapped_processes:
        proc.check()
    if all(proc.success for proc in wrapped_processes):
        print("All processes ended successfully")
        break
    time.sleep(1)
```

It's also easy to add a "max time" feature here (when starting a new process, store the current time; have `check()` terminate a process if it's overdue).

Comment: above sol is not working, above code prints both "Starting" and "Failed" for all .exes including successful and Failed processes.

Comment: `Starting C:\Users\XYZ\PycharmProjects\Task1\dist\multiof1.exe
Failed: C:\Users\XYZ\PycharmProjects\Task1\dist\multiof1.exe` -- OUTPUT

Comment: Oops – fixed that bug.