# How to get terminate or run code after a line that is blocking the code and does not pass command to next line?

Tags: python, linux, bash, terminal

I am trying to get the **IP address** and **other details of Linux** through my **python code**. when `tmp = subprocess.call("./a.out")` this line executes the code **sticks** here and this line `subprocss.call("ifconfig")` is not executed. as I cannot change the **C code**. so how can I make the next line run.

```
def execute():
    dirname = '/home/kali/Downloads'
    ext = ('.py','.c','.sh')
    try:
        for files in os.listdir(dirname):
            if files.endswith(ext):
                if files.endswith('.c'):
                    subprocess.call(["gcc", "code.c"])
                    tmp = subprocess.call("./a.out")
                    subprocss.call("ifconfig")
```

Comment: For non-blocking `subprocess.call`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071866/non-blocking-subprocess-call

Comment: The bug is in ```code.c``` -- look there to see why it doesn't return

Comment: actually, code.c elevates the privileges and make me root user now the root terminal pops up and block the rest code

Comment: I also checked `Subprocess.Popen` but it does not work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got answer for this question after a long time of research. It can be done with a function `subprocess.communicate` function.
this function can communicate with the process.