# Turn Screensaver off on macOS Monterey via Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, screensaver

I have a Python media player that I want to turn off the screensaver while the video is playing. This works great on Windows, but I can't get it to work on the Mac. The top code with the caffeine module works in PyCharm. Unfortunately, when the program is compiled it crashes at this point. Unfortunately the other code snippets don't work, or am I making an obvious mistake?

```
def turn_screen_saver_off():
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        print("turn_screen_saver_off")
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(0x80000002)
    elif sys.platform == "darwin":
        print("turn_screen_saver_off")
        #import caffeine
        #caffeine.on(display=True)
        
        #subprocess.run(['caffeinate', '-s']) # Keep the system awake
        
        #from AppKit import NSBundle
        #bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        #info = bundle.localizedInfoDictionary() or bundle.infoDictionary()
        #info['NSScreensaverDisabled'] = True
        
        #script = 'tell application "System Events" to set sleep to 0'
        #os.system(f"osascript -e '{script}'")


def turn_screen_saver_on():
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        print("turn_screen_saver_on")
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(0x80000000)
    elif sys.platform == "darwin":
        print("turn_screen_saver_on")
        #import caffeine
        #caffeine.off()
        
        #subprocess.run(['killall', 'caffeinate']) # Allow the system to sleep
        
        ##from AppKit import NSBundle
        #bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        #info = bundle.localizedInfoDictionary() or bundle.infoDictionary()
        #info['NSScreensaverDisabled'] = True
        
        #script = 'tell application "System Events" to set sleep to 1'
        #os.system(f"osascript -e '{script}'")
```

I tried following code. But it doesn't work.

```
        #import caffeine
        #caffeine.on(display=True)
        
        #subprocess.run(['caffeinate', '-s']) # Keep the system awake
        
        #from AppKit import NSBundle
        #bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        #info = bundle.localizedInfoDictionary() or bundle.infoDictionary()
        #info['NSScreensaverDisabled'] = True
        
        #script = 'tell application "System Events" to set sleep to 0'
        #os.system(f"osascript -e '{script}'")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try saving the screen saver time with this commmand:

```
 defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver idleTime
```

Then try modifying the screen saver default directly with this command:

```
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver idleTime 0
```

Found this solution on [this blog](https://medium.com/@rksingh0399/how-to-turn-off-screen-saver-in-mac-using-terminal-command-a3d3a84d7a6a) check it out if you'd like!

Comment: Thank you! But in this solution if the script turns the screensaver on again, I have to put in a value like 5 for 5 min. Some users have set a different time like 10 min or 15 min so the player changes the users default setting. It shouldn't be like that.

Comment: you could get the users default time before running the command with this. defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver idleTime.

Comment: Is there an better, safer solution?

Comment: Just looked into it the parameter `-s` in your current caffeinate command; is only valid when the computer is running on AC power. To have caffeinate work more holistically use a command like this `caffeinate -d -i -u -s `. You can reference specific needs with the man-page. Hope this helps.

Comment: When the subprocess function is executed the GUI hangs completely :-(

Comment: This is because subproces.call and subprocess.run in your code are blocking functions that return "CompletedProcess" instances. You need to use subprocess.Popen or asyncio. Here's some code I found to help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071866/non-blocking-subprocess-call

Comment: Also make sure you can stop it later by saving the subprocess result and maintaining the process id. Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true