# How can I run crawling task while flask application is running?

Tags: flask

I wrote `crawling.py`  inside my flask project folder to periodically fetch some data.

**crawling.py**

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
import os
import json
import requests
import schedule
import time

def fetchAndStoreData():
  // some codes...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db = connectDB()
    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(fetchAndStoreData, db)

    while True:
      schedule.run_pending()
      time.sleep(1)
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
import subprocess
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

def crawling():
   os.chmod('crawling.py', 0o700)
   subprocess.call('python3 crawling.py', shell=True)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
   ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
   crawling()
   app.run('0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

How do I perform crawling of the crawling.py file while I'm running the flask application?

I would like to make crawling task run in the background of my flask application.

Is running the crawling.py file and the flask app independently from the command line the only solution?

I tried using subprocess but it didn't work.

Comment: The threading module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) might do the trick for you. However running two independent processes is the cleaner solution in my opinion

Comment: See for example [Non blocking subprocess.call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071866/non-blocking-subprocess-call) but is there a problem with running the processes separately from the shell?