# Is it possible to run some code while Python computes another piece of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, load

Say you wrote a function that returns the factorial of a number (factorial of 5 is 120 because 5*4*3*2*1=120) so if you have a huge number clearly it's going to take python a while to figure it out. Is it possible to have it run some while loop or something that runs while python figures out the factorial of x?

Comment: Yes that is possible. It is called multithreading. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python) is a good explanation with some examples how to do it in python.

Comment: @Flomp that's not a good idea: threads implementation in python are, lets say "not ideal". Read about GIL to see why.

Comment: This is a broad question, I'm going to close it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'd rather find something close enough to be a dup. That's not broad - the OP asks how to run code concurrently in python. A legit question.

Comment: @alfasin Sorry... should've been clear - I was going to close this as a dupe :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is to generate another process that will calculate factorial concurrently to the work that your current process is doing.

There's a module called [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) that might interest you. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606867/what-is-the-difference-between-multiprocessing-and-subprocess).