# Does using the subprocess module release the python GIL?

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, python-multithreading, gil

When calling a linux binary which takes a relatively long time through Python's `subprocess` module, does this release the GIL?

I want to parallelise some code which calls a binary program from the command line. Is it better to use threads (through `threading` and a `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`) or `multiprocessing`? My assumption is that if `subprocess` releases the GIL then choosing the `threading` option is better.

Comment: Please clarify.  The current answers think you are worried about the child process itself somehow holding the GIL, but I think you are perhaps concerned that `subprocess.call()` or `subprocess.Popen(...).wait()` will block other threads in the caller.  (They do not.)

Comment: @pilcrow: As someone who come across this question from Google, I would suggest you turn your comment into an answer, because unlike the existing answers it addresses the actual question.

Answer (score 17):

> When calling a linux binary which takes a relatively long time through Python's `subprocess` module, does this release the GIL?

Yes, it releases the [Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) in the calling process.

As you are likely aware, on POSIX platforms `subprocess` offers convenience interfaces atop the "raw" components from `fork`, `execve`, and `waitpid`.

By inspection of the CPython 2.7.9 sources, `fork` and `execve` do *not* release the GIL.  However, those calls do not block, so we'd not expect the GIL to be released.

`waitpid` of course *does* block, but we see it's implementation does give up the GIL using the `ALLOW_THREADS` macros:

```cpp
static PyObject *
posix_waitpid(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
....
Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
pid = waitpid(pid, &status, options);
Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
....
```

This could also be tested by calling out to some long running program like [*sleep*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//utilities/sleep.html) from a demonstration multithreaded python script.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, CPython releases GIL while using blocking OS API such as `waitpid()`. There is nothing specific about methods from `subprocess` module. Note: `execve()` obviosly blocks (*in the child* after the fork in this case) -- it returns only on error. `fork()` is a special case: ["read this discussion to understand why you should avoid mixing multithreading and `fork()`](http://bugs.python.org/issue6721) (`fork()` immidiately followed by `exec()` is fine).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: yes re: rule of thumb and the dangers of mixing threads and forks.  I'd question the characterization of `execve()` as "blocking," however.  A successful `execve` doesn't block the caller, it vaporizes the caller.

Answer (score 7):

GIL doesn't span multiple processes. `subprocess.Popen` starts a new process. If it starts a Python process then it will have its own GIL.

You don't need multiple threads (or processes created by `multiprocessing`) if all you want is to run some linux binaries in parallel:

```
from subprocess import Popen

# start all processes
processes = [Popen(['program', str(i)]) for i in range(10)]
# now all processes run in parallel

# wait for processes to complete
for p in processes:
    p.wait()
```

You could [use `multiprocessing.ThreadPool` to limit number of concurrently run programs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14533902/4279).

Comment: Should be `multiprocessing.Pool`

Comment: @DanqiWang: no. `multiprocessing` provides both a process-based Pool and a thread-based Pool with identical interfaces. Both can be used depending on circumstances.

Comment: I don't understand why you have a preference of `TheadPool` over `pool` here. `Pool` can also limit the number of concurrency and the running processes will not suffer from the GIL. Moreover, `ThreadPool` is poorly documented.

Comment: @DanqiWang: Popen starts *new* process; there are no GIL issues as the first paragraph in the answer says. You could use `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool` (same thing as `ThreadPool`) then all you need to change your code from using threads to using processes is to remove `.dummy` from the import. The interface is identical.

Comment: Understood. Didn't notice that it's `Popen`. My bad. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: This won't work if you need to send data to the process or retrieve the output. For that you need to use communicat() which waits for the process to terminate.

Comment: @T3rm1 wrong. 1- the code in the answer works as is. 2- Here's [how to adapt it, to get output from multiple processes concurrently.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23616229) Though it has nothing to do with the GIL (which is released during blocking I/O operations)

Answer (score 1):

Since `subprocess` is for running executable (it is essentially a wrapper around `os.fork()` and `os.execve()`), it probably makes more sense to use it. You can use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). Something like:

```
 import subprocess

 process = subprocess.Popen(["binary"])
```

This will run in as a separate process, hence not being affected by the GIL. You can then use the [`Popen.poll()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) method to check if child process has terminated:

```
if process.poll():
    # process has finished its work
    returncode = process.returncode
```

Just need to make sure you don't call any of the methods that *wait* for the process to finish its work (e.g. [Popen.communicate()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)) to avoid your Python script blocking.

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629680/deciding-between-subprocess-multiprocessing-and-thread-in-python)

> `multiprocessing` is for running functions within your existing
>   (Python) code with support for more flexible communications among the
>   family of processes. `multiprocessing` module is intended to provide
>   interfaces and features which are very similar to threading while
>   allowing CPython to scale your processing among multiple CPUs/cores
>   despite the GIL.

So, given your use-case, `subprocess` seems to be the right choice.

Comment: `process.stdout.readlines()` may block forever if any of the child processes fill any of their stderr pipe buffers. If you want to read both stdout and stderr separately then you need [asynchronous approach: threads or non-blocking pipes or iocp on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/375427/4279)

Comment: Absolutely right! I had forgotten about that. Thanks.