# Designing a good architecture for python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a program (say, "prog")  written in C that makes many numerical operations. I want to write  a "driver" utility in python that runs the "prog" with different configurations in a parallel way, reads its outputs and logs them. There are several issues to take into account:

1. All sort of things can go bad any time so logging has to be done as soon as possible after any `prog` instance finishes.
2. Several `prog`s can finish simultaneously so logging should be done centralized
3. workers may be killed somehow and `driver` has to handle that situation properly
4. all workers and logger must be terminated correctly without tons of backtraces when `KeyboardInterrupt` is handled

The first two points make me think that all workers have to send their results to some centralized `logger` worker through for example `multiprocessing.Queue`. But it seems that the third point makes this solution a bad one because if a worker is killed the queue is going to become corrupted. So the Queue is not suitable. Instead I can use multiple  process to process pipes (i.e. every worker is connected through the pipe with a logger). But then the other problems raise:

1. reading from pipe is a blocking operation so one logger can't read asynchronously from several workers (use threads?)
2. if a worker is killed and a pipe is corrupted, how the logger can diagnose this?

P.S. point #4 seems to be solveable -- a have to

1. disable default SIGINT handling in all workers and logger;
2. add `try except` block to main process that makes `pool.terminate();pool.join()` calls in case of SIGINT exception handled.

Could you please suggest a better design approach if possible and if not than how to tackle the problems described above?

P.S. python 2.7

Comment: My advice is to read these two articles first - (1) http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/03/31/pythons-hardest-problem/ and (2) https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/06/30/pythons-hardest-problem-revisited/ . The first one explains why Python might not be the best option for concurrency and the second - some ways of improving this drawback.

Comment: @rbaleksandar. Ha! You know, I was thinking that using Threads was not the way to go BUT the GIL maybe can really solve the problem! Each worker start the `prog` with subprocess.call(...) and after that saves the output to some shared variable. Owing to GIL, writing to shared variable will be absolutely safe. Despite thread locking the spawned `prog`s will run parallel.  And there will be no need in all that bulky inter-process messaging tools. What do you think?

Comment: Are you able to modify `prog` or is it fixed and we can't touch it?  What sort of input and output does it do?

Comment: @JohnZwinck It's fixed. It takes a configuration file as input and outputs some formatted metrics to stdout. `driver` is responsible for configuration file preparation, spawning `prog`s  and fetching their output.

Comment: The behaviour you're describing reminds me a LOT of how ROS (robot operating system) works. Especially the logging part is done pretty neatly there. May I suggest that you first look into it (that is - look at solutions that are already implemented and well tested)? Also the interpreter choice in this case is crucial. PyPy or Jython are a good pick (you can read a short overview of both in the second article I have posted in my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from the answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23369802/4323

The idea is to not use `subprocess.call()` which is blocking, but instead `subprocess.Popen` which is non-blocking.  Set `stdout` of each instance to e.g. a `StringIO` object you create for each `prog` child.  Spawn all the `prog`s, wait for them, write their output.  Should be not far off from the code shown above.