# subprocess.Popen works but any sort of wait (call, wait, communicate) causes "Not Responding"

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

This works:

```
def letsExecute():
    import subprocess
    subpr = subprocess.Popen("python " + codeFile + spacedout)
```

This causes the program to not respond (I'm running on windows):

```
def letsExecute():
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call("python " + codeFile + spacedout)
```

`wait`, `communicate` and basically anything that makes the main process wait for the sub process causes the same. I want the main process to quit when the subprocess finishes successfully.

Also, FYI: this function is hooked to a tkinter Button, and this program uses tkinter GUI and a mainloop(). Dunno if this affects this problem, but letting you know anyway.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your code.

[`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

> *Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute*.

[`wait()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) and [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) are also blocking functions.

Use [`poll()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) instead.

```
subpr = subprocess.Popen(["python", codeFile, spacedout])

while subpr.poll() is None:
    print("Still working...")
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Since you want the GUI thread to be responsive you can start the sub-process on a different thread. something like this,

```
import subprocess
import threading
import time

def letsExecute():
   t = threading.Thread(target=realExec)
   t.run()

def realExec():
   proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", codeFile, spacedout])

   while proc.poll() is None:
       print("Still working...")
       time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why you trying to `subprocess` another python script when you can just import it?

Anyway, you problem stems from the fact that any of `call`, `wait` and `communicate` waits for termination of `subprocess` if `timeout` parameter is ommited. Because of this `tkinter` application unable to refresh itself and `mainloop` is unreachable for code flow.

If you have something complicated in your mind - take a look at [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16031801/6634373) topic.

If you want just terminate the main process when the subprocess finishes - take a look at thoose snippets:

**test.py:**

```
import time

time.sleep(5)
```

**main.py:**

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

import subprocess

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='Start', command=self.start_test_process)
        self.button.pack()
        self.process = None

    def continuous_check(self):
        status = self.process.poll()

        if status is None:
            print('busy')
            self.after(500, self.continuous_check)
        elif status == 0:
            print('successfully finished')
            self.destroy()
        else:
            print('something went wrong')

    def start_test_process(self):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen('python test.py')
        self.continuous_check()


app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

The main idea here in keep `mainloop` reachable for code with combination of [`poll`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) and [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) methods.