# run multiple python scripts at the same time

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, spyder

Is there a way to run multiple python scripts simultaneously in vsc. I mean while there is already a script running, I would like to run another script. When I try I get "code is already running".
In spyder-ide I simply open a new IPython console and run the new script in this newly opened console.

Comment: It is not related to vsc or spyder but hope this might give you some thought.

People use Python for everything, from short scripts to running Instagram.  .

If you want to execute multiple files at once you could consider a shell script or using something like ***subprocess*** in Python's stdlib to run multiple files simultaneously.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can always open a terminal terminal window -- with either `Python: Create Terminal` or `Open New Terminal` -- and launch the script(s) manually in separate terminals.

Comment: "at the same time" please read carefully the cuestion

Answer (score 6):

If you need to coordinate execution and communicate between these programs, you'll need to use [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). If the scripts can run independently, you can run them manually at the same time from a terminal, or use a subprocess call from the first script:

```
subprocess.call(['python', 'secondscript.py', secondscript_arg1, secondscript_val1,...]).
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

It will create a new terminal and you can run another script.

Comment: "at the same time" please read carefully the cuestion

Comment: At the same time, you can run using this method, I run always in vscode.

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension called "Code Runner" extension developped by Jun Han, after install it, right click on the second script, select "Run Code".

Comment: This extension is very poor with options (like ctrl-c it for example), it only runs simple programs that stop by themselves.

Answer (score 2):

### Brief answer:

Create a debug configuration and run the script with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>. A button for this can be configured.

### Elaborate answer:

There are multiple ways to run a Python file in VS Code. There is the triangular "Run" button (typically in the top right corner of the window) and there is the triangular "Run" button in the ["Run and debug" view](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_run-and-debug-view) in the primary side panel. Use the latter one.

- If there is no debug configuration yet, open the menu next to the run button and click on "add configuration ([your source folder])".
- The `launch.jason` file should open.
- Add a configuration like the one below (there can be multiple configurations, and you can adjust them to your liking):

```json
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "suppressMultipleSessionWarning": true,
        }
]
```

- Go to your source file and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>. This will run your file with the configuration specified in the debug view, [but the file will not be debugged](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_run-mode).
- You can run the same file or different files simultaneously that way. If the option `suppressMultipleSessionWarning` is not set or set to `false`, you will see a warning.
- Because the "default" run button in the top right corner is typically not doing what I want, I disabled it (right click -> disable "run and debug").

#### Adding a "proper" run button to the task bar

- If you do not like to use your keyboard, you can create a button for running. You may use the extension "[Task Buttons](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spencerwmiles.vscode-task-buttons)".
- Install the extension.
- Add a task to your `tasks.json` like this:

```json
"tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Run",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${command:workbench.action.debug.run}",
        }
]
```

- Then add a button that executes this task (in `settings.json`):

```json
"VsCodeTaskButtons.tasks": [
            {
                "label": "Run",
                "task": "Run",
                "tooltip": "Run Python file",
            }
]
```

---

**Disclaimer**: I did not have time to double check my answer in a fresh installation of VSCode without extensions. If the answer does not work for you, please write a comment, and I will do my best to check which extensions may be required.

Answer (score 2):

In VS code GUI you can click on "Run Python File in Dedicated Terminal" as well. It's pretty easy and straightforward.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

open a new angle of the visual studio then open the other file in this new one, so you can run it

Answer (score -3):

You could install PyCharm which has a plugin called 'Multirun'.This allows you to run several python files in parallel. I had the same issue as you and fixed it this way.

Answer (score -3):

Use **Sublime Text 3** and run your script by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> shortcut

Comment: "at the same time" please read carefully the cuestion and the program is VSCode