# Running Python scripts simultaneously in VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Consider the following scenario: I have two Python scripts, the first a long-running process and the second a short-running process. I heavily use the `shift` + `enter` shortcut to run code directly from my `.py` files.

Currently in VS Code, I can only manage to have the interactive environment with one script. That is, if I run the first, long-running script and then open a new Python terminal window, running a line such as `print('hello world')` will run in the first terminal. I want to learn how to change the `shift` + `enter` so that it executes in the second, newly-opened terminal window.

I've looked at a few SO questions, namely [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969662/run-multiple-python-scripts-at-the-same-time) one, but the solutions either don't work or are not applicable to my use case.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to execute in the newly-opened terminal window typing a command there. Not as convenient as shift + enter but does the job.